# REINF - Assinatura Inválida

Tags: c#, xml, web-service

Estou desenvolvendo uma mensageria para o reinf mas estou com problemas para enviar o primeiro evento. Ao enviar um R1000 estou recebendo a mensagem:

*MS0017*

*Assinatura do evento inválida. Assinatura Digital do documento XML é inválida*

Estou gerando o xml do evento utilizando a classe XmlSerializer. Primeiro faço download dos arquivos xsd do reinf, passo eles no xsd.exe para gerar as classes em C#, gero um objeto do evento, preencho as propriedades e depois serializo conforme abaixo:

```
XmlSerializer ArquivoSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
using (FileStream ArquivoStream = new FileStream(pObjArquivo.FullName, FileMode.CreateNew))
{
  using (XmlWriter ArquivoWriter = XmlWriter.Create(ArquivoStream))
  {
    ArquivoSerializer.Serialize(ArquivoWriter, pSerializableObject);
  }
  return new FileInfo(ArquivoStream.Name);
}
```

Até aqui tudo bem. Depois o manual pede para enviarmos o evento na forma de lotes envelopados. Criar o xml dos lotes do mesmo modo não funcionou. O Reinf rejeita o arquivo gerado a partir de seu xsd de envio de lotes, então bolei uma alternativa:

```
XNamespace ns = "http://www.reinf.esocial.gov.br/schemas/envioLoteEventos/v1_01_01";

XDocument eventoAssinado = XDocument.Load(pFileEventoAssinado.FullName);

XDocument doc = new XDocument(
            new XElement(ns + "Reinf",
                         new XAttribute("xmlns", ns.NamespaceName),
                         new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "xsd", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"),
                         new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"),
                         new XElement(ns + "loteEventos",
                            new XElement(ns + "evento",
                                         new XAttribute("id", pFileEventoAssinado.Name.Replace(".xml", string.Empty)),
                                         new XElement(eventoAssinado.Root)
                                        ))
                         ));
```

Este xml sim é processado pelo reinf, porém retornando o erro do início da pergunta. A pergunta é: Será que quando estou adicionando a Root do meu eventoAssinado ao novo xml isso gera alguma alteração no próprio evento assinado, inválidando minha assinatura? Alguem consegue me recomendar uma prática melhor que esta?

Utilizo o mesmo método de assinatura no eSocial sem problemas.

Comment: Eu tive esse problema porque o texto não era UTF-8. Tente forçar o encoding UTF-8. Dá uma olhada [neste link](https://ideiasdefenestradas.wordpress.com/2017/11/27/reinf-continuando-a-trabalhar-de-graca-para-o-governo/) também.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta @heringer ! Tentei utilizar o UTF-8 na assinatura, geração do xml e do lote do arquivo e não funcionou. O Reinf continua me retornando o mesmo erro.

Não consegui utilizar o método de assinatura do link que mandou pois ao tentar realizar a assinatura pelo método SignedXml.ComputeSignature() com o DigestMethod = "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256&#8221" recebo uma exception dizendo que não foi possível criar o algoritmo de hash. Só funciona quando utilizo "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256", sem o "&#8221". É a única coisa que está diferente.

Comment: esse "&#8243" aí é o código de aspas. O post no link está errado, foi mal. Pode arrancar isso.

Comment: Não sei se você já conseguiu resolver, mas se precisar ainda, disponibilizei uma implementação com teste unitário [neste link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bxb3pxCHYFruVll5eWVLLVM1UkNIWEpkSVVQOUF6VTV2cThB/view?usp=sharing). Se quiser usar, edite as constantes da classe PseudoTeste. Uma é o número de série do certificado e a outra é o CNPJ da empresa dona do certificado.

Comment: Consegui realizar o envio na manhã de hoje.
Vou postar uma resposta detalhando o problema e a solução pra posteridade rs.
Sua resposta foi fundamental para a resolução @heringer, muito obrigado.

Comment: @JamesBraz, olhei que você conseguiu resolver o problema da assinatura do evento, você chegou a comentar que iria publicar a resposta detalhando a resolução do problema. Publiquei um pergunta recentemente, pois estou com o mesmo problema, segue a pergunta: [Reinf Assinatura Inválida](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/264812/reinf-assinatura-inv%C3%A1lida-falha-ao-verificar-a-assinatura-do-documento-xml-r) Se puder contribuir com a sua resposta detalhada eu agradeço muito pois ainda permaneço com o problema, obrigado.

Answer (score 3):

James, uma diferença entre o eSocial e o EFD-Reinf, até a última vez que testei o Reinf (estou mais voltado ao desenvolvimento para o eSocial) era que no Reinf era necessário informar "#IdDoEvento" no elemento URI da assinatura, ao passo que o elemento URI no eSocial deve ser vazio.

Eu também fiz algo com parecido com o que você fez, usei a ferramenta XSD.exe para criar objetos a partir dos XSDs disponibilizados pelo governo, mas, respondendo sua pergunta, também usei o objeto gerado a partir do XSD para manipular o lote de envio, algo como:

```
 lote.envioLoteEventos.eventos.evento[iCount] = new EnvioLoteEventos.TArquivoEsocial();
 lote.envioLoteEventos.eventos.evento[iCount].Id = idEvento;
 // Serializa o objeto para um documento XML e o assina.
 var eventoAssinado = SerializaEAssina(evento, certificado);
 // Adiciona o XML assinado do evento ao array de eventos do lote.
 lote.envioLoteEventos.eventos.evento[iCount].Any = eventoAssinado.DocumentElement;
```

Eu tenho um exemplo de XML que foi enviado com sucesso para o EFD-Reinf, na época que testei:
http://suporte.quarta.com.br/eSocial/arquivos/R1000_EnvioLote.xml

Comment: Por que essa resposta está sendo negativada se ela dá uma dica para responder a pergunta original ("Assinatura do evento inválida" -> Deve ser informado o ID do evento no elemento URI) e ainda sugere uma solução para um problema comentado na pergunta original ("Criar o xml dos lotes do mesmo modo não funcionou" -> Postei um trecho de código que permite embutir o evento assinado no objeto do lote, sem precisar criar o XML de lote na mão), e ainda possui link para um exemplo de lote válido do EFD-Reinf?

Comment: Pedro, excelente resposta, votei na sua resposta, ela foi muito válida para me ajudar a resolver o problema. Não esquenta com a negativação a ignorância faz essas coisas.