# EFD-Reinf: Assinatura inválida - Falha ao verificar a assinatura do documento XML (usando C#)

Tags: c#, assinatura, sha-256, web-service

Boa tarde, alguém conseguiu realizar a assinatura do evento do EFD-Reinf usando C#?

Estou enviando o evento assinado e está retornando a seguinte ocorrência:

```
{
<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>
<dadosRegistroOcorrenciaEvento>
    <ocorrencias>
        <tipo>1</tipo>
        <localizacaoErroAviso/>
        <codigo>MS0017</codigo>
        <descricao>Assinatura do evento inválida. Falha ao verificar a assinatura do documento XML</descricao>
    </ocorrencias>
</dadosRegistroOcorrenciaEvento>
}
```

Estou utilizando o seguinte código para assinar o evento:

```
 String id = @event.Attributes.GetNamedItem("id").Value;


 SignedXml signature = new SignedXml(@event);

 Reference reference = new Reference();
 reference.Uri = "#" + id;

 XmlDsigEnvelopedSignatureTransform env = new 
 XmlDsigEnvelopedSignatureTransform();
 reference.AddTransform(env);

 XmlDsigC14NTransform c14 = new XmlDsigC14NTransform();
 reference.AddTransform(c14);

 reference.DigestMethod = "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256";

 KeyInfo keyInfo = new KeyInfo();

 keyInfo.AddClause(new KeyInfoX509Data(certificate));

 signature.SigningKey = certificate.GetRSAPrivateKey();
 signature.AddReference(reference);
 signature.KeyInfo = keyInfo;
 signature.SignedInfo.SignatureMethod = "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256";
 signature.ComputeSignature();

 var reinfEvent = @event.GetElementsByTagName("Reinf").Item(0);
 reinfEvent.AppendChild(signature.GetXml());
```

Alguém já passou por essa situação?

Answer (score 3):

Muriel, eu já passei por essa situação e hoje consigo assinar os eventos com sucesso. Estou trabalhando com o eSocial, mas, o código é basicamente o mesmo e eu cheguei a testar o envio de um R-1000 no EFD-Reinf, também com sucesso.

Algumas dicas básicas que devem ser seguidas para realizar a assinatura com sucesso:

- Você deve usar somente o XML do evento para gerar a assinatura, e depois o XML do evento assinado é embutido no XML do lote. O XML do lote nunca deve ser assinado, somente os eventos, individualmente, são assinados.
- A tag raiz do evento, *Reinf*, não deve conter os elementos **xmlns:xsi** e **xmlns:xsd**, que normalmente são adicionados automaticamente pelo serializador.
- Depois de assinado, o XML do evento não deve sofrer **nenhuma** alteração, porque senão a assinatura se torna inválida. Eu já vi pessoas que alteravam coisas manualmente no XML depois de assinado, e já aconteceu comigo do XML do evento ser gravado em disco usando um encoding e a gravação do XML de lote, com o evento assinado embutido, usar outro enconding, o que também invalidava a assinatura.

Eu fiz uma página há um tempo atrás com algumas dicas sobre como assinar um XML de evento do eSocial:

> http://suporte.quarta.com.br/eSocial/AssinaturaXml.htm

Mas, resumindo, o código que estou usando para o eSocial é o seguinte:

```
  //
  // SignedXml.CheckSignature Method (X509Certificate2, Boolean) -> Examples [SHA1]
  // https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms148731(v=vs.110).aspx
  //
  // Using SHA256 with the SignedXml Class
  // https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/winsdk/2015/11/14/using-sha256-with-the-signedxml-class/
  //
  private static void SignXmlDoc(XmlDocument xmlDoc, X509Certificate2 certificate)
  {
     //
     // https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/whats-new/#Crypto462
     //
     // SignedXml support for SHA-2 hashing The .NET Framework 4.6.2 adds support
     // to the SignedXml class for RSA-SHA256, RSA-SHA384, and RSA-SHA512 PKCS#1
     // signature methods, and SHA256, SHA384, and SHA512 reference digest algorithms.
     //
     // Any programs that have registered a custom SignatureDescription handler into CryptoConfig
     // to add support for these algorithms will continue to function as they did in the past, but
     // since there are now platform defaults, the CryptoConfig registration is no longer necessary.
     //
     //// First of all, we need to register a SignatureDescription class that defines the DigestAlgorithm as SHA256.
     //// You have to reference the System.Deployment assembly in your project.
     //CryptoConfig.AddAlgorithm(
     //   typeof(System.Deployment.Internal.CodeSigning.RSAPKCS1SHA256SignatureDescription),
     //   "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256");
     // RSAPKCS1SHA256SignatureDescription -> Disponível desde .NET Framework 4.5

     SignedXml signedXml = new SignedXml(xmlDoc);

     // Add the key to the SignedXml document. 
     signedXml.SigningKey = certificate.GetRSAPrivateKey();   // Disponível desde .NET Framework 4.6
     //signedXml.SigningKey = GetRSAPrivateKey(certificate);

     //
     // https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/whats-new/#Crypto462
     //
     // SignedXml support for SHA-2 hashing The .NET Framework 4.6.2 adds support
     // to the SignedXml class for RSA-SHA256, RSA-SHA384, and RSA-SHA512 PKCS#1
     // signature methods, and SHA256, SHA384, and SHA512 reference digest algorithms.
     signedXml.SignedInfo.SignatureMethod = SignedXml.XmlDsigRSASHA256Url; //"http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256"

     // Create a reference to be signed. Pass "" to specify that
     // all of the current XML document should be signed.
     Reference reference = new Reference(string.Empty);

     reference.AddTransform(new XmlDsigEnvelopedSignatureTransform());
     reference.AddTransform(new XmlDsigC14NTransform());
     reference.DigestMethod = SignedXml.XmlDsigSHA256Url; //""http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"

     // Add the reference to the SignedXml object.
     signedXml.AddReference(reference);

     signedXml.KeyInfo = new KeyInfo();
     // Load the certificate into a KeyInfoX509Data object
     // and add it to the KeyInfo object.
     signedXml.KeyInfo.AddClause(new KeyInfoX509Data(certificate));

     // Compute the signature.
     signedXml.ComputeSignature();

     // Get the XML representation of the signature and save
     // it to an XmlElement object.
     XmlElement xmlDigitalSignature = signedXml.GetXml();

     // Append the element to the XML document.
     xmlDoc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(xmlDoc.ImportNode(xmlDigitalSignature, true));

     if (xmlDoc.FirstChild is XmlDeclaration)
        xmlDoc.RemoveChild(xmlDoc.FirstChild);
  }
```

No EFD-Reinf a única diferença é que o elemento Reference.URI deve conter o ID do evento, com o caractere **#** na frente (coisa que você já está fazendo), ao passo que no eSocial esse elemento deve estar vazio. Então para o EFD-Reinf a linha que cria o objeto *reference*, nessa função que te passei, deve ser alterada para:

```
     Reference reference = new Reference("#" + idEvento);
```

Segue um exemplo de lote do Reinf que foi enviado com sucesso:

> http://suporte.quarta.com.br/eSocial/arquivos/R1000_EnvioLote.xml