# C# EFD-REINF 1.03.02 - Assinatura do evento inválida. Assinatura Digital do documento XML é inválida

Tags: c#, web-service, api

tudo bom?

Estou tentando realizar a cáspeta da assinatura digital do **EFD-REINF** (A versão mais recente ***1.03.02***) do XML de evento (nesse caso estou testando com o R1000) com **.Net C#**, mas **framework 4.0**.

Eu realmente não sei se estou fazendo algo de errado, mas já tentei várias coisas para tentar assinar o xml do evento e não consigo, estou sempre recebendo a **MS0017 - Assinatura do evento inválida. Assinatura Digital do documento XML é inválida**.

Olhem abaixo, é o código que eu estou utilizando para assinar o bloco do evento.

```
public static System.Xml.XmlElement XmlAssinado(object reinf, string cpfCnpj, string id)
{
    var certificate = GetCertificado(cpfCnpj);
    var xml = reinf.ToXmlString();
    var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();

    xmlDoc.LoadXml(xml);

    if (xmlDoc.FirstChild is XmlDeclaration)
        xmlDoc.RemoveChild(xmlDoc.FirstChild);

    //if (xmlDoc.FirstChild.Attributes["xmlns:xsi"] != null)
    //    xmlDoc.FirstChild.Attributes.Remove(xmlDoc.FirstChild.Attributes["xmlns:xsi"]);

    //if (xmlDoc.FirstChild.Attributes["xmlns:xsd"] != null)
    //    xmlDoc.FirstChild.Attributes.Remove(xmlDoc.FirstChild.Attributes["xmlns:xsd"]);

    Reference reference = new Reference($"#{id}");

    // 1 - Transformação exigida - Envelop
    XmlDsigEnvelopedSignatureTransform env = new XmlDsigEnvelopedSignatureTransform();
    reference.AddTransform(env);

    // 2 - Transformação exigida - C14N
    XmlDsigC14NTransform c14 = new XmlDsigC14NTransform();
    reference.AddTransform(c14);

    // Message Digest
    reference.DigestMethod = "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256";

    // Load the certificate into a KeyInfoX509Data object
    // and add it to the KeyInfo object.
    KeyInfo keyInfo = new KeyInfo();
    keyInfo.AddClause(new KeyInfoX509Data(certificate));

    //XmlDocument documentoUTF8 = ReconstruirComoUTF8(xmlDoc);

    // Instancia a classe de criptografia
    //var signedXml = new SignedXml(documentoUTF8);
    var signedXml = new SignedXml(xmlDoc);
    // Define as propriedades da assinatura
    // Adiciona a chave ao documento assinado

    RSACryptoServiceProvider key = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
    key.FromXmlString(certificate.PrivateKey.ToXmlString(true));

    signedXml.SigningKey = key; //.GetRSAPrivateKey();http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1

    // Adiciona a referência ao documento assinado
    signedXml.AddReference(reference);
    signedXml.KeyInfo = keyInfo;
    signedXml.SignedInfo.SignatureMethod = "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256";

    // Gera a assinatura
    signedXml.ComputeSignature();

    // Obtém a representação em XML da assinatura e salva em um objeto XmlElement
    XmlElement xmlDigitalSignature = signedXml.GetXml();

    // Append the element to the XML document.
    xmlDoc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(xmlDoc.ImportNode(xmlDigitalSignature, true));

    if (xmlDoc.FirstChild is XmlDeclaration)
        xmlDoc.RemoveChild(xmlDoc.FirstChild);

    return xmlDoc.DocumentElement;
}
```

Esse **object** é a estrutura do evento em *Objeto*.

Abaixo é o xml de saída de como está ficando o XML:

```
<Reinf xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://www.reinf.esocial.gov.br/schemas/envioLoteEventos/v1_03_02">
<loteEventos>
    <evento id="ID1111111110000002017102714215100001">
        <Reinf xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://www.reinf.esocial.gov.br/schemas/evtInfoContribuinte/v1_03_02">
            <evtInfoContri id="ID1111111110000002017102714215100001">
                <ideEvento>
                    <tpAmb>2</tpAmb>
                    <procEmi>1</procEmi>
                    <verProc>SAP ECC 6.0</verProc>
                </ideEvento>
                <ideContri>
                    <tpInsc>1</tpInsc>
                    <nrInsc>15622088000150</nrInsc>
                </ideContri>
                <infoContri>
                    <inclusao>
                        <idePeriodo>
                            <iniValid>2018-01</iniValid>
                        </idePeriodo>
                        <infoCadastro>
                            <classTrib>99</classTrib>
                            <indEscrituracao>1</indEscrituracao>
                            <indDesoneracao>0</indDesoneracao>
                            <indAcordoIsenMulta>0</indAcordoIsenMulta>
                            <contato>
                                <nmCtt>xxxxxxxxxxx</nmCtt>
                                <cpfCtt>111111111</cpfCtt>
                                <foneFixo>11111111111</foneFixo>
                                <email>aaaaaaaa@bbbbb.com</email>
                            </contato>
                        </infoCadastro>
                    </inclusao>
                </infoContri>
            </evtInfoContri>
            <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                <SignedInfo>
                    <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315" />
                    <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256" />
                    <Reference URI="#ID1111111110000002017102714215100001">
                        <Transforms>
                            <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" />
                            <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315" />
                        </Transforms>
                        <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256" />
                        <DigestValue>yBmhSIzReZE0+WLAqgxjoSqq2tZZEThdZIHx5uRiffI=</DigestValue>
                    </Reference>
                </SignedInfo>
                <SignatureValue>gF/YxdCbbPM8dd0qdBdcnALwk0zvMRWSxLqqdda/qbeYFDQ30/1m38oO80EXeZgab1e79SxLYDwOQleWknUKFxa5r+u+3mmCdy2Bgq0YJxdZ16PSEQnVTwDJDguXMyaWY76OoqIQdcqm35m11hmPRJZtkuKatgBce/pksWDZqI/2GdEUrWFPx+FB6Luto9IFt3RRxon6gQN6M3jsmd8c3BMu34TCD53JfgyTm1WqQBNtGj+fLYbC/eyItG2DI+8x3mb4WtKS3KqDUSqzZvOKj9GKTtg92+TsJurJrVsq3CZVGgClvcTCOsmP0ByES1ninFDaMEeFPKOzz8Mirz2Xsw==</SignatureValue>
                <KeyInfo>
                    <X509Data>
                        <X509Certificate>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</X509Certificate>
                    </X509Data>
                </KeyInfo>
            </Signature>
        </Reinf>
    </evento>
</loteEventos>
```

Se alguém conseguir me auxiliar, eu agradeço imensamente!
Muito grato desde já.

Comment: essa mensagem é o servidor que está recebendo o xml, que te retorna? ou é um erro que ocorre em tempo de execução?

Comment: esse id `<evtInfoContri id="ID1111111110000002017102714215100001">` é gerado baseado em algum critério?

Comment: @RodrigoK.B, sse mensagem é o servidor da receita que está me retornando sim. E o ID, NESSE CASO, foi gerado na mão, mesmo, respeitando só o limite de caracteres.

Comment: Eu tive um problema parecido com outro serviço ws da receita. Resolvi acrescentando o carácter _ no início do id. Ou seja o id ficaria assim "_ID2332887733398878900000098822".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

boa tarde! Consegui resolver o meu problema, reescrevi a função de assinatura, ao que parece com o Framework 4.0 a forma é um pouco mais complexa para assinar o mesmo, segue abaixo a função, caso alguém trombe com o mesmo problema:

Referente aos parâmetros:

- **pUri**: É o nome do nó principal do XML que será assinado, no caso, é sempre o "***Reinf***"
- **noPrincipal**: É o nome do nó do evento, é necessário pois a assinatura vem logo depois desse nó. Exemplo: no caso do evento R1000, o nó do evento é o "***evtInfoContri***"
- **objToTransform**: É o objeto do evento que será assinado

Estou usando uma classe estendida para a serialização/deserealização dos objetos em XML

.

```
    public static XmlElement AssinarXml(string pUri,string noPrincipal, object objToTransform)
    {
        XmlDocument documento = new XmlDocument();
        documento.LoadXml(objToTransform.ToXmlString());

        if (documento.FirstChild is XmlDeclaration)
            documento.RemoveChild(documento.FirstChild);

        if (documento.FirstChild.Attributes["xmlns:xsi"] != null)
            documento.FirstChild.Attributes.Remove(documento.FirstChild.Attributes["xmlns:xsi"]);

        if (documento.FirstChild.Attributes["xmlns:xsd"] != null)
            documento.FirstChild.Attributes.Remove(documento.FirstChild.Attributes["xmlns:xsd"]);

        string subject = String.Empty;

        X509Certificate2 pCertificado = null;
        System.Security.Cryptography.AsymmetricAlgorithm pKey = null;

        if (pCertificado != null)
            subject = pCertificado.Subject.ToString();

        // parametros de retorno
        string XMLAssinado = String.Empty;

        try
        {
            try
            {
                int qtdeRefUri = documento.GetElementsByTagName(pUri).Count;

                if (qtdeRefUri == 0)
                    throw new Exception(string.Format("A tag de assinatura {0} não existe.", pUri.Trim()));
                else
                {
                    try
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < qtdeRefUri; i++)
                        {
                            SignedXml docXML = new SignedXml(documento);

                            Reference reference = new Reference();
                            XmlAttributeCollection uri = documento.GetElementsByTagName(pUri).Item(i).Attributes;
                            var nrInscr = documento.GetElementsByTagName("nrInsc")[0].FirstChild.Value;

                            pCertificado = GetCertificado(nrInscr);
                            pKey = pCertificado.PrivateKey;

                            foreach (XmlAttribute atributo in uri)
                            {
                                if (atributo.Name == "id" || atributo.Name == "Id" || atributo.Name == "ID")
                                    reference.Uri = "#" + atributo.InnerText;
                            }

                            // adicionando EnvelopedSignatureTransform a referencia
                            XmlDsigEnvelopedSignatureTransform envelopedSigntature = new XmlDsigEnvelopedSignatureTransform();
                            reference.AddTransform(envelopedSigntature);

                            XmlDsigC14NTransform c14Transform = new XmlDsigC14NTransform();
                            reference.DigestMethod = "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256";
                            reference.AddTransform(c14Transform);

                            docXML.AddReference(reference);

                            // carrega o certificado em KeyInfoX509Data para adicionar a KeyInfo
                            KeyInfo keyInfo = new KeyInfo();
                            keyInfo.AddClause(new KeyInfoX509Data(pCertificado));
                            docXML.KeyInfo = keyInfo;

                            // SHA256
                            var exportedKeyMaterial = pCertificado.PrivateKey.ToXmlString(/* includePrivateParameters = */ true);
                            var key = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(new CspParameters(24 /* PROV_RSA_AES */));
                            key.PersistKeyInCsp = false;
                            key.FromXmlString(exportedKeyMaterial);

                            docXML.SigningKey = key;
                            // -----------------
                            docXML.SignedInfo.SignatureMethod = "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256";
                            docXML.ComputeSignature();

                            // recuperando a representacao do XML assinado
                            XmlElement xmlDigitalSignature = docXML.GetXml();

                            documento.GetElementsByTagName(noPrincipal).Item(i).AppendChild(documento.ImportNode(xmlDigitalSignature, true));
                            //documento.GetElementsByTagName(noPrincipal).Item(1).AppendChild(documento.ImportNode(xmlDigitalSignature, true));

                            // teste Charset                                
                            Encoding iso = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1");
                            Encoding utf8 = Encoding.UTF8;
                            byte[] utfBytes = utf8.GetBytes(documento.OuterXml);
                            byte[] isoBytes = Encoding.Convert(utf8, iso, utfBytes);
                            XMLAssinado = iso.GetString(isoBytes);

                            //XMLAssinado = documento.OuterXml;
                        }
                    }
                    catch (CryptographicException ex)
                    {
                        throw new Exception(string.Format("Erro ao assinar o documento - {0}", ex.Message));
                    }
                    catch (Exception caught)
                    {
                        throw new Exception(string.Format("Erro ao assinar o documento - {0}", caught.Message));
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception caught)
            {
                throw new Exception(string.Format("XML mal formado - {0}", caught.Message));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception caught)
        {
            throw new Exception(string.Format("Problema ao acessar o certificado digital - {0}", caught.Message));
        }

        XmlDocument any = new XmlDocument();
        any.LoadXml(XMLAssinado);

        return any.DocumentElement;
    }
```

Segue abaixo a classe estendida de deserealização/serialização

```
public static class XmlTools
{
    public static string ToXmlString<T>(this T input)
    {
        string _return = string.Empty;
        using (StringWriter stringwriter = new Utf8StringWriter())
        {
            System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer x = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(input.GetType());
            x.Serialize(stringwriter, input);
            _return = stringwriter.ToString();
        }

        return _return.ToString();
    }

    public static T ToObject<T>(this string objectToDeserialize)
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(objectToDeserialize.ToString()));

        return (T)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
    }

    public static I ToObject<T, I>(this T objectToDeserialize, I classePara)
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(I));
        XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(objectToDeserialize.ToString()));

        return (I)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
    }
}

public class Utf8StringWriter : StringWriter
{
    // Use UTF8 encoding but write no BOM to the wire
    public override Encoding Encoding
    {
        get { return new UTF8Encoding(false); } // in real code I'll cache this encoding.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Algumas dicas básicas que devem ser seguidas para realizar a assinatura com sucesso:

- Você deve usar somente o XML do evento para gerar a assinatura, e depois o XML do evento assinado é embutido no XML do lote. O XML do lote nunca deve ser assinado, somente os eventos, individualmente, são assinados.
- A tag raiz do evento, *Reinf*, não deve conter os elementos **xmlns:xsi** e **xmlns:xsd**, que normalmente são adicionados automaticamente pelo serializador.
- Depois de assinado, o XML do evento não deve sofrer **nenhuma** alteração, porque senão a assinatura se torna inválida. Eu já vi pessoas que alteravam coisas manualmente no XML depois de assinado, e já aconteceu comigo do XML do evento ser gravado em disco usando um encoding e a gravação do XML de lote, com o evento assinado embutido, usar outro enconding, o que também invalidava a assinatura.

Veja essas duas respostas aqui:

> EFD-Reinf: Assinatura inválida - Falha ao verificar a assinatura do documento XML
>   https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/277476/86952
>
> Erro de assinatura do XML para o EFD-Reinf
>   https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/283284/86952

Comment: opa Pedro, blz? Eu cheguei a ver essas respostas já, mas não consegui solucionar o meu problema. Sabe se esse lance dos atributos **xmlns:xsi** e **xmlns:xsd** mesmo para a versão 1.03.02 se mantém? Tentei retirar tbm, mas não funcionou.

Comment: Eu acredito que se mantenha sim, o eSocial também não aceita os atributos. Algumas perguntas: 1) Esse objeto `reinf` que você passa para a função `XmlAssinado`, começa a partir do segundo nó *Reinf* do XML, certo? 2) Depois você adiciona o retorno da função `XmlAssinado` ao XML do lote? 3) Como está fazendo para salvar o arquivo XML final? 4) O campo *id* deve conter a data em que o evento foi gerado, e eu notei que o seu id tem esse valor: "20171027", o que significaria que o evento foi gerado em 27/10/2017; para um evento gerado em 03/05/2018, por exemplo, esse trecho deveria ser "20180503".

Comment: Pedrão, consegui resolver reescrevendo a função de assinatura, mas seguem as respostas para as suas perguntas: 1) Isso, esse objeto é só o bloco do evento, sem o nó principal. Estou assinando os eventos individualmente. 2) Na verdade, após a assinatura do evento, eu adiciono o nó da assinatura dentro do nó do evento mesmo, mas logo abaixo, respeitando o xsd. 3) O XML final eu recupero com uma função de _serealização_ de objetos, que transforma os objetos em XML 4) O campo id foi enviado só respeitando a quantidade, pois o mesmo será enviado por uma outra interface.