# WebService REINF

Tags: web-service

Ao tentar enviar o xml R1000 recebo a seguinte erro:
"The HTTP request was forbidden with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'."

Alguem pode me dar uma força?

Comment: Você precisa acessar o serviço usando um certificado digital. Qual linguagem de programação está usando?

Comment: Consegui por aqui , 
Obrigado.

Comment: @PedroGaspar boa tarde,
Vi varios de seus posts que me ajudaram muito no processo todo.
No momento já consegui assinar o XML mas estou recebendo menssagem de ID-Inválido.
Tem alguma dica?

Comment: O melhor seria você elaborar uma nova pergunta com essa dúvida, porque pode ajudar outros também. Coloque o máximo de detalhes que puder, inclusive a linguagem de programação que está usando, a mensagem de erro e qual ID está informando. Muito provavelmente deve ser o formato do ID que deve estar incorreto. Inclusive, se puder poste aqui também qual foi a solução desta sua pergunta, porque pode ajudar outros, que é a intenção do StackOverflow! :-)  
Aliás, não sei se você já viu essa página que dá uma geral do funcionamento do site: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Resolvido - Obrigado pela dica do Tour do site.
Quanto ao erro do ID-Invalido consegui resolver.
O problema ocorria devido a alteração manual que eu estava fazendo da URI=”#ID1111.....”. 
Encontrei esta informação em um de seus posts. (https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/295153/c-efd-reinf-1-03-02-assinatura-do-evento-inv%C3%A1lida-assinatura-digital-do-docu/295159#295159)

Comment: Que bom que resolveu. Quando encontrar alguma dica útil, você pode dar um voto positivo no post, assim ele se torna mais relevante e pode ser achado mais facilmente, e, nesse caso, me daria alguns pontinhos também! :-)