# Erro na assinatura de XML para o EFD-Reinf em Elixir

Tags: web-service, elixir

Segui as instruções postadas neste [link:](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/283260/erro-de-assinatura-do-xml-para-o-efd-reinf)

Este fora bastante esclarecedor, mas ainda estou com problemas para realizar a assinatura do XML do REINF, utilizando Elixir como linguagem.

No exemplo que coloco abaixo, estou tentando assinar o evento "evtInfoContri", o formato que estou usando para assinar é desta forma:

```
<Reinf xmlns="http://www.reinf.esocial.gov.br/schemas/evtInfoContribuinte/v1_03_02"><evtInfoContri id="ID1142933600000002018051414491100281"><ideEvento><tpAmb>2</tpAmb><procEmi>1</procEmi><verProc>V2R010</verProc></ideEvento><ideContri><tpInsc>1</tpInsc><nrInsc>14293360</nrInsc></ideContri><infoContri><inclusao><idePeriodo><iniValid>2018-01</iniValid></idePeriodo><infoCadastro><classTrib>99</classTrib><indEscrituracao>1</indEscrituracao><indDesoneracao>1</indDesoneracao><indAcordoIsenMulta>0</indAcordoIsenMulta><indSitPJ>0</indSitPJ><contato><nmCtt>CARLOS DOMIENIKAN</nmCtt><cpfCtt>18293491809</cpfCtt><foneFixo>1149021845</foneFixo><email>carlos@cdomienikan.com</email></contato></infoCadastro></inclusao></infoContri></evtInfoContri></Reinf>
```

Como tento mostrar, este XML está em uma única linha. Para assinatura e criação do digest, estou usando o módulo ExCrypto, realizando as seguintes instruções:

```
rsa_priv_key     = ExPublicKey.load!("priv/cert/private_rsa.key")
{:ok, hash}      = ExCrypto.Hash.sha256(evento())
digest           = "#{Base.encode64 hash}"
{:ok, signature} = ExPublicKey.sign(eventoXML(), :sha256, rsa_priv_key)
base64           = "#{Base.encode64 signature}"
```

Depois de realizado isso, meu XML assinado fica desta forma (Adendo: Por motivos de segurança por serem informações particulares do meu cliente, os dados foram modificados aqui, logo não necessariamente fora montado desta forma)

```
<Reinf xmlns="http://www.reinf.esocial.gov.br/schemas/evtInfoContribuinte/v1_03_02"><evtInfoContri id="ID1142933600000002018051414491100281"><ideEvento><tpAmb>2</tpAmb><procEmi>1</procEmi><verProc>V2R010</verProc></ideEvento><ideContri><tpInsc>1</tpInsc><nrInsc>12345678</nrInsc></ideContri><infoContri><inclusao><idePeriodo><iniValid>2018-01</iniValid></idePeriodo><infoCadastro><classTrib>99</classTrib><indEscrituracao>1</indEscrituracao><indDesoneracao>1</indDesoneracao><indAcordoIsenMulta>0</indAcordoIsenMulta><indSitPJ>0</indSitPJ><contato><nmCtt>Empresa XPTO</nmCtt><cpfCtt>12345678999</cpfCtt><foneFixo>1123456789</foneFixo><email>meu@email.com</email></contato></infoCadastro></inclusao></infoContri></evtInfoContri><Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"><SignedInfo><CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"/><SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256"/><Reference URI="#ID1142933600000002018051414491100281"><Transforms><Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/><Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"/></Transforms><DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/><DigestValue>Valor do digest em Base64</DigestValue></Reference></SignedInfo><SignatureValue>Valor da assinatura em Base64</SignatureValue><KeyInfo><X509Data><X509Certificate>Valor do certificado</X509Data></KeyInfo></Signature></Reinf>
```

e depois de envelopado ficou assim:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:sped="http://sped.fazenda.gov.br/"><soapenv:Header/><soapenv:Body><sped:ReceberLoteEventos><sped:loteEventos><Reinf xmlns="http://www.reinf.esocial.gov.br/schemas/envioLoteEventos/v1_03_02"><loteEventos><evento id="ID1142933600000002018051414491100281"><Reinf xmlns="http://www.reinf.esocial.gov.br/schemas/evtInfoContribuinte/v1_03_02"><evtInfoContri id="ID1142933600000002018051414491100281"><ideEvento><tpAmb>2</tpAmb><procEmi>1</procEmi><verProc>V2R010</verProc></ideEvento><ideContri><tpInsc>1</tpInsc><nrInsc>12345678</nrInsc></ideContri><infoContri><inclusao><idePeriodo><iniValid>2018-01</iniValid></idePeriodo><infoCadastro><classTrib>99</classTrib><indEscrituracao>1</indEscrituracao><indDesoneracao>1</indDesoneracao><indAcordoIsenMulta>0</indAcordoIsenMulta><indSitPJ>0</indSitPJ><contato><nmCtt>Empresa XPTO</nmCtt><cpfCtt>12345678999</cpfCtt><foneFixo>1123456789</foneFixo><email>meu@email.com</email></contato></infoCadastro></inclusao></infoContri></evtInfoContri><Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"><SignedInfo><CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"/><SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256"/><Reference URI="#ID1142933600000002018051414491100281"><Transforms><Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/><Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"/></Transforms><DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/><DigestValue>Valor do digest em Base64</DigestValue></Reference></SignedInfo><SignatureValue>Valor da assinatura em Base64</SignatureValue><KeyInfo><X509Data><X509Certificate>Valor do certificado</X509Data></KeyInfo></Signature></Reinf></evento></loteEventos></Reinf></sped:loteEventos></sped:ReceberLoteEventos></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
```

Mesmo fazendo desta forma, obtenho como resultado a mensagem MS0017.

O que pode estar errado?

Muito obrigado pela atenção de todos,

Comment: Pacheco, talvez o problema esteja nesse namespace **sped**, e nesses dois elementos, `sped:ReceberLoteEventos` e `sped:loteEventos`, que aparecem antes do primeiro elemento `Reinf`, no pacote SOAP final. Veja esse XML de exemplo (está numa versão super defasada, mas, dá para ter uma ideia de como deveria ser), ele funcionou na época em que foi enviado: http://suporte.quarta.com.br/eSocial/arquivos/R1000_EnvioLote.xml

Comment: Então... Eu testei com e sem essas tags e ocorre erros diferentes... Sem elas tenho o erro MS0028 - Lote inválido e com elas tenho o erro MS0017 - Assinatura inválida. Eu já tentei assinar o XML inteiro (a string) e também somente o ID, em ambos ocorrem o erro MS0017, como disse. Deixo uma pergunta: O que seria correto, para assinar o XML? Usar a string inteira ou apenas o valor do ID (ex.: "ID1142933600000002018051414491100281"). Quanto o digest, como eu calculo ele?

Comment: Veja essa outra resposta que eu dei, para você ter uma ideia melhor de como tem que fazer: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/295159/86952

Comment: Eu cheguei a ver e segui exatamente essa resposta https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/283260/erro-de-assinatura-do-xml-para-o-efd-reinf/283284#283284, mesmo assim minha assinatura apresenta erro. Eu peguei o XML, conforme coloquei aqui e gerei a assinatura dele e o digest tbm, conforme solicitado pela receita.

Comment: Pacheco, notei agora que no seu exemplo do XML assinado, faltou fechar o elemento `<X509Certificate>`. Você removeu sem querer essa tag de fechamento quando editou o valor desse elemento, ou o seu XML está com esse erro mesmo?