# Como consumir WebService do EFD-Reinf no C#? (Envio Eventos)

Tags: c#, web-service

Estou iniciando os testes de envio de informações do EFD-Reinf, em C#.
Pelo Visual Studio, adicionei uma `Service Reference` no meu projeto com a URL:

> https://preprodefdreinf.receita.fazenda.gov.br/wsreinf/RecepcaoLoteReinf.svc?singleWsdl

Estou com o certificado digital instalado na minha máquina.
Ele solicita permissão para usar a chave:

[image: Permissão da chave]

Ele carrega os serviços disponíveis, clico OK e o serviço está disponível para mim. Consigo instanciar, etc.

Pergunto, como devo proceder a partir daí?

Pois com outros WebServices, como o dos Correios, eu fazia desta forma: instanciava, passava os parâmetros e o WS me retornava com a resposta, e com o da EFD-Reinf não sei como passar tais parâmetros.

Para quem já desenvolveu, esta é a melhor forma de enviar os eventos da EFD-Reinf?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O código principal para acessar o WebService do EFD-Reinf é esse:

```
using System.Net;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.Xml.Linq;

public void EnviarLoteReinf()
{
   // Carrega o certificado digital a partir de um arquivo PFX, informando a senha.
   X509Certificate2 x509Cert = new X509Certificate2(caminhoArquivoPfx, senhaArquivoPfx);
   // Carrega o XML de lote a partir de um arquivo.
   // Mas os XMLs dos eventos devem ser assinados digitalmente antes de inseridos no XML de lote.
   // Para isso é possível usar a função SignXmlDoc() disponível na resposta abaixo:
   // https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/277476/
   XDocument loteEventosXDoc = XDocument.Load(caminhoArquivoXml);

   var urlServicoEnvio = @"https://preprodefdreinf.receita.fazenda.gov.br/wsreinf/RecepcaoLoteReinf.svc";
   var address = new EndpointAddress(urlServicoEnvio);
   // BasicHttpsBinding está disponível somente a partir do .NET Framework 4.5.
   // Se estiver usando uma versão anterior, use a linha comentada abaixo.
   //var binding = new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpsSecurityMode.Transport);
   var binding = new BasicHttpsBinding();

   // Informa que será usado um certificado digital para acessar o serviço.
   binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Certificate;

   // Veja essa pergunta para mais detalhes:
   // https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/318351/
   ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls;

   // Cria o objeto cliente (do tipo System.ServiceModel.ClientBase) para acesso ao WebService.
   var wsClient = new ServiceReference2.RecepcaoLoteReinfClient(binding, address);
   // Passa o certificado digital para o objeto do tipo System.ServiceModel.ClientBase.
   wsClient.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate = x509Cert;

   // Veja: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49303859/
   wsClient.Open();
   // Chama o WebService de fato, passando o XML do lote.
   // O método espera um objeto do tipo XElement, e retorna outro objeto XElement.
   var retornoEnvioXElement = wsClient.ReceberLoteEventos(loteEventosXDoc.Root);
   wsClient.Close();
}
```

---

Alguns pontos importantes (e outros nem tanto) que estão parcialmente comentados no código, ou estão relacionados:

- O XML que será enviado para o serviço é um arquivo de lote que conterá um ou mais eventos do EFD-Reinf. Esses XMLs dos eventos devem ser assinados [individualmente](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/283284/86952) antes de serem inseridos ao lote. Nessa [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/277476/) há um exemplo de função para assinar o XML usando o certificado digital;
- A classe `System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpsBinding` está disponível somente a partir do .NET Framework 4.5, se estiver usando uma versão anterior, use a classe `BasicHttpBinding`;
- Para maiores detalhes sobre a linha `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls`, veja [essa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/318351/);
- Para uma informação interessante sobre `System.ServiceModel.ClientBase.Open()` veja [essa resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49303859/);
- Se quiser ver um exemplo de tratamento de exceções retornadas por um WebService WCF, veja [essa resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49271080/).

---

Aqui vão alguns links úteis para trabalhar com o EFD-Reinf:

- [Leiautes EFD-Reinf](http://sped.rfb.gov.br/pasta/show/2133);
- [Esquemas XSD](http://sped.rfb.gov.br/pasta/show/2141);
- [Manual de Orientação ao Desenvolvedor](http://sped.rfb.gov.br/pasta/show/2225).

Comment: Muito obrigado Pedro!!. Consegui.! Apenas tive que migrar do Visual Studio 2010 para o Visual Studio 2017 por causa do framework!.  Apenas está me retornando um erro de versão do lote:  <descricao>Versão do lote inválida. Deve ser utilizada a versão 1.04.00.</descricao>. Devo abrir outra pergunta ou continuo neste post?

Comment: Vagner, que bom que funcionou! Mas a melhor forma de agradecer por uma resposta é marcando ela como aceita, clicando no sinal de visto (✓). Quando atingir 15 pontos de reputação também poderá [votar a favor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) de uma resposta ou pergunta. Veja: [Alguém me respondeu](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) e [Por que votar?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote). Faça também o [tour], para uma explicação inicial de como o site funciona.

Comment: Melhor abrir outra pergunta Vagner, porque é outra dúvida totalmente diferente. Mas pode colocar um link para essa pergunta, na sua nova pergunta, para contextualizar melhor e não precisar repetir texto e código.

Comment: Apesar que, nessa minha resposta mesmo, tem o link para os Esquemas XSD no final, e lá tem um link para o [Pacote XSD de Comunicação v1.4](http://sped.rfb.gov.br/arquivo/show/2803), que é o mais atual e o que deve ser usado. Provavelmente será só você atualizar para esse esquema que deve funcionar.