# EFD-Reinf - Versão do lote inválida. Deve ser utilizada a versão 1.04.00

Tags: c#, web-service

Estou gerando o registro R-1000 para teste de envio no ambiente de produção restrita do EFD-Reinf, e já obtive ajuda aqui no SOpt mesmo:
[Como consumir WebService do EFD-Reinf no C#? (Envio Eventos)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/343132/como-consumir-webservice-do-efd-reinf-no-c-envio-eventos).

Consegui autenticar e fazer o consumo do serviço com sucesso, porém o retorno do XML enviado diz que a versão está inválida:

> Versão do lote inválida. Deve ser utilizada a versão 1.04.00.

Sendo que aponto para a nova:
`http://www.reinf.esocial.gov.br/schemas/envioLoteEventos/v1_04_00`

Já pesquisei aqui no SOpt, inclusive no post:
[C# EFD-REINF 1.03.02 - Assinatura do evento inválida. Assinatura Digital do documento XML é inválida](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/295153/c-efd-reinf-1-03-02-assinatura-do-evento-inv%C3%A1lida-assinatura-digital-do-docu), mas não encontrei a causa do problema.

Segue o XML que estou enviando, sem assinatura:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:sped="http://sped.fazenda.gov.br/">
  <soap:Header />
  <soap:Body>
    <REINF xmlns="http://www.reinf.esocial.gov.br/schemas/envioLoteEventos/v1_04_00">
      <loteEventos>
        <evento id="ID1">
          <Reinf xmlns="http://www.reinf.esocial.gov.br/schemas/evtInfoContribuinte/v1_04_00">
            <evtInfoContri id="20181121110000000000000001">
              <ideEvento>
                <tpAmb>2</tpAmb>
                <procEmi>1</procEmi>
                <verProc>1.0</verProc>
              </ideEvento>
              <ideContri>
                <tpInsc>1</tpInsc>
                <nrInsc>01628604</nrInsc>
              </ideContri>
              <infoContri>
                <inclusao>
                  <idePeriodo>
                    <iniValid>2018-01</iniValid>
                  </idePeriodo>
                  <infoCadastro>
                    <classTrib>99</classTrib>
                    <indEscrituracao>1</indEscrituracao>
                    <indDesoneracao>0</indDesoneracao>
                    <indAcordoIsenMulta>0</indAcordoIsenMulta>
                    <indSitPJ>0</indSitPJ>
                    <contato>
                      <nmCtt>XXXX</nmCtt>
                      <cpfCtt>XXX</cpfCtt>
                      <foneFixo>(011)XXXX6427</foneFixo>
                      <email>XXXXX</email>
                    </contato>
                  </infoCadastro>
                </inclusao>
              </infoContri>
            </evtInfoContri>
          </Reinf>
        </evento>
      </loteEventos>
    </REINF>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

O XML com a assinatura:

```xml
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:sped="http://sped.fazenda.gov.br/">
  <soap:Header />
  <soap:Body>
    <REINF xmlns="http://www.reinf.esocial.gov.br/schemas/envioLoteEventos/v1_04_00">
      <loteEventos>
        <evento id="ID1">
          <Reinf xmlns="http://www.reinf.esocial.gov.br/schemas/evtInfoContribuinte/v1_04_00">
            <evtInfoContri id="20181121110000000000000001">
              <ideEvento>
                <tpAmb>2</tpAmb>
                <procEmi>1</procEmi>
                <verProc>1.0</verProc>
              </ideEvento>
              <ideContri>
                <tpInsc>1</tpInsc>
                <nrInsc>01628604</nrInsc>
              </ideContri>
              <infoContri>
                <inclusao>
                  <idePeriodo>
                    <iniValid>2018-01</iniValid>
                  </idePeriodo>
                  <infoCadastro>
                    <classTrib>99</classTrib>
                    <indEscrituracao>1</indEscrituracao>
                    <indDesoneracao>0</indDesoneracao>
                    <indAcordoIsenMulta>0</indAcordoIsenMulta>
                    <indSitPJ>0</indSitPJ>
                    <contato>
                      <nmCtt>xxx</nmCtt>
                      <cpfCtt>xxx</cpfCtt>
                      <foneFixo>(011)xxx</foneFixo>
                      <email>xxxx</email>
                    </contato>
                  </infoCadastro>
                </inclusao>
              </infoContri>
            </evtInfoContri>
          </Reinf>
        </evento>
      </loteEventos>
    </REINF>
  </soap:Body>
  <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
    <SignedInfo>
      <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315" />
      <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256" />
      <Reference URI="">
        <Transforms>
          <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" />
          <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315" />
        </Transforms>
        <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256" />
        <DigestValue>Mv9GEVe2dZ4zstZhfcp0xok3OHolN5kjUNtMDvG1uF4=</DigestValue>
      </Reference>
    </SignedInfo>
    <SignatureValue>DUE7Q+LguONd8cDbPZHqC9ObqG51Um5Oh4v7I5fMw43zIQQeeMbhF2j1GrbKg0poFW134OUB1dFXZyXMEQ/ynrNXkRXT1zZAXgQ0jFtfUA6MIjDCUoE68Q/bNDG7N28A1loXqAILKMmVr8WGg73UA9rDU9wMTTWy9yOfN712yqFA5RJzp53wpVX6BmjC05lfRblslEcSZTvQg2QbgLh+FBRIubznVn+sFuZ5hAB6QggCumSyxVBrpeLPyvlpSPvQM2xHw4IO3bFSq2BqPHSePU3lLyl+8/irlOLUGYSSX77m8hmBOpKzmqBqjX+v8E6QLHLEUpXcN0HT3Y5bGMByrQ==</SignatureValue>
    <KeyInfo>
      <X509Data>
        <X509Certificate>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</X509Certificate>
      </X509Data>
    </KeyInfo>
  </Signature>
</soap:Envelope>
```

O XML completo de retorno:

```xml
<Reinf xmlns="http://www.reinf.esocial.gov.br/schemas/retornoLoteEventos/v1_04_00">
  <retornoLoteEventos id="IDCE8ED92E6A9124FCD401AFF46756541E">
    <ideTransmissor>
      <IdTransmissor>01628604000140</IdTransmissor>
    </ideTransmissor>
    <status>
      <cdStatus>1</cdStatus>
      <descRetorno>ERRO</descRetorno>
      <dadosRegistroOcorrenciaLote>
        <ocorrencias>
          <tipo>1</tipo>
          <codigo>MS0092</codigo>
          <descricao>Versão do lote inválida. Deve ser utilizada a versão 1.04.00.</descricao>
        </ocorrencias>
      </dadosRegistroOcorrenciaLote>
    </status>
  </retornoLoteEventos>
  <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
    <SignedInfo>
      <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315" />
      <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256" />
      <Reference URI="#IDCE8ED92E6A9124FCD401AFF46756541E">
        <Transforms>
          <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" />
          <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315" />
        </Transforms>
        <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256" />
        <DigestValue>gRHi6NxvLDuhFO2Q2jB+Nl7B450LCzRynii+Mo10ZWE=</DigestValue>
      </Reference>
    </SignedInfo>
    <SignatureValue>CmbAd77rYGrwWkFSw+Hx4BqnbV7bgjGfnnw2Y1TkQt1HYJIjoe7JcjBO8v/BFmg0vzHMU4CLr4GuryhMFFP1m6ED/OhAbH1DAqwmPITypfSnLTZno5ILgxtV1mxic88oYY3VebPZnAeINg7OK1u+J3tQMmpEuTx0ew7kY5wIFOW+Fa2bUQXGRqrLP2r5C7Gmt+b/Z0mHxLAaeb/qwdhxqnyDVuCayFo93dI5rREP9WgQhTijwRv8k0uBQ94bOzv12kcF15w00rg3F/1bo6Vy8iSzFc9OtEl0C5tUMC765QnfFChdWdkT9BtQwVnKiOHTGISixa9EHpzjEv24cGvrPA==</SignatureValue>
    <KeyInfo>
      <X509Data>
        <X509Certificate>MIIHcTCCBVmgAwIBAgIDAvA9MA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBCwUAMIGOMQswCQYDVQQGEwJCUjETMBEGA1UECgwKSUNQLUJyYXNpbDE2MDQGA1UECwwtU2VjcmV0YXJpYSBkYSBSZWNlaXRhIEZlZGVyYWwgZG8gQnJhc2lsIC0gUkZCMTIwMAYDVQQDDClBdXRvcmlkYWRlIENlcnRpZmljYWRvcmEgZG8gU0VSUFJPUkZCIFNTTDAeFw0xODA5MDQxNzA5NDhaFw0xOTA5MDQxNzA5NDhaMIG6MQswCQYDVQQGEwJCUjETMBEGA1UECgwKSUNQLUJyYXNpbDE2MDQGA1UECwwtU2VjcmV0YXJpYSBkYSBSZWNlaXRhIEZlZGVyYWwgZG8gQnJhc2lsIC0gUkZCMREwDwYDVQQLDAhBUlNFUlBSTzEaMBgGA1UECwwRUkZCIGUtU2Vydmlkb3IgQTExLzAtBgNVBAMMJnByZXByb2RlZmRyZWluZi5yZWNlaXRhLmZhemVuZGEuZ292LmJyMIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAq+gp3NABZzSp4S1I7c6lgJXp1NgCOjHKn5OMxisk68fuHbhj1eyzfSMkc281ecF0uCmW+Fwyz7wnwRvS/VDE9/1p/21rg85AyzWvYfTvBcHKpi83d6PBmczt7xMNf8FRLU5Zj8dAS84YkoGBZw3GQTfWqW9LLnOf1zPmaPgdN8ALjecUkFmFIWNQLDgARR0YBIrTVtmk/BRZKk6z/j/gSHClhEy6ZCplVna5i9YJnDOoXlVuflEIuVMyRR2+SyuNk2QI5K/+vURKnZzY2xQKEfCBzu+Xj8ceuXHmtA75X03cKauCOq/Jqklfp9nY1ZvdXc4/lJXyFxf8iFfLAMHiDQIDAQABo4ICqDCCAqQwHwYDVR0jBBgwFoAUII0RXFXDAW+rVvGDzGipq8LatWMwXgYDVR0gBFcwVTBTBgZg
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</X509Certificate>
      </X509Data>
    </KeyInfo>
  </Signature>
</Reinf>
```

**EDIÇÃO**
Tem razão, não havia percebido que a assinatura deve ser por evento e não por lote.

Sobre "A forma correta do seu soap:Envelope deveria ser essa":
fiz a edição conforme indicado, mas continua retornando a mesma mensagem de lote errado:

```
{<Reinf xmlns="http://www.reinf.esocial.gov.br/schemas/retornoLoteEventos/v1_04_00">
  <retornoLoteEventos id="ID54ED726E636E2B6F9FD4FD7077870873">
    <ideTransmissor>
      <IdTransmissor>01628604000140</IdTransmissor>
    </ideTransmissor>
    <status>
      <cdStatus>1</cdStatus>
      <descRetorno>ERRO</descRetorno>
      <dadosRegistroOcorrenciaLote>
        <ocorrencias>
          <tipo>1</tipo>
          <codigo>MS0092</codigo>
          <descricao>Versão do lote inválida. Deve ser utilizada a versão 1.04.00.</descricao>
        </ocorrencias>
      </dadosRegistroOcorrenciaLote>
    </status>
  </retornoLoteEventos>
  <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
    <SignedInfo>
      <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315" />
      <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256" />
      <Reference URI="#ID54ED726E636E2B6F9FD4FD7077870873">
        <Transforms>
          <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" />
          <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315" />
        </Transforms>
        <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256" />
        <DigestValue>PkXxGAtPdkWYgZ21TLotsVYYE7mPLGnmpmLMXI65gnQ=</DigestValue>
      </Reference>
    </SignedInfo>
     [...]</SignatureValue>
    <KeyInfo>
      <X509Data>
        <X509Certificate> [...]</X509Certificate>
      </X509Data>
    </KeyInfo>
  </Signature>
</Reinf>}
    BaseUri: ""
    Document: null
    FirstAttribute: {xmlns="http://www.reinf.esocial.gov.br/schemas/retornoLoteEventos/v1_04_00"}
    FirstNode: {<retornoLoteEventos id="ID54ED726E636E2B6F9FD4FD7077870873" xmlns="http://www.reinf.esocial.gov.br/schemas/retornoLoteEventos/v1_04_00">
  <ideTransmissor>
    <IdTransmissor>01628604000140</IdTransmissor>
  </ideTransmissor>
  <status>
    <cdStatus>1</cdStatus>
    <descRetorno>ERRO</descRetorno>
    <dadosRegistroOcorrenciaLote>
      <ocorrencias>
        <tipo>1</tipo>
        <codigo>MS0092</codigo>
        <descricao>Versão do lote inválida. Deve ser utilizada a versão 1.04.00.</descricao>
      </ocorrencias>
    </dadosRegistroOcorrenciaLote>
  </status>
</retornoLoteEventos>}
    HasAttributes: true
    HasElements: true
    IsEmpty: false
    LastAttribute: {xmlns="http://www.reinf.esocial.gov.br/schemas/retornoLoteEventos/v1_04_00"}
    LastNode: {<Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
  <SignedInfo>
    <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315" />
    <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256" />
    <Reference URI="#ID54ED726E636E2B6F9FD4FD7077870873">
      <Transforms>
        <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" />
        <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315" />
      </Transforms>
      <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256" />
      <DigestValue>PkXxGAtPdkWYgZ21TLotsVYYE7mPLGnmpmLMXI65gnQ=</DigestValue>
    </Reference>
  </SignedInfo>
  <SignatureValue>NaDYeZv3gFDBH41BY5j8hcYXHhpdx+hjFWCIYvLaBxAVWNUUaAZixzV3Bld4Lul3m0yKL6Hq16xmKYiA55tCPbZWWy+YymnCtj3OC7rZPv2lQZZyTK6DiLugIIiUyk7TsTd1rZmT6D55OxwJfpmb1M+rQLK6siYAZmI2pguUX0NvKITIaaxUD6HGZOgO6cc9VGRR7PTxjhkl0j0jcwFPxCEvk8cTbT0PnkkLw1v5zPBC1nvgpz3Kn+fG11qkTwEIIdNonx/O1i7ZdvpLUe7/MXEYNbip/lcrGL/zapBHNTsLgN6NNI7QUUuPIPB4yMhpQcNA9FfzEgzdZVhbDzdLeQ==</SignatureValue>
  <KeyInfo>
    <X509Data>
      <X509Certificate> [...]</X509Certificate>
    </X509Data>
  </KeyInfo>
</Signature>}
    Name: {{http://www.reinf.esocial.gov.br/schemas/retornoLoteEventos/v1_04_00}Reinf}
    NextNode: null
    NodeType: Element
    Parent: null
    PreviousNode: null
    Value: "016286040001401ERRO1MS0092Versão do lote inválida. Deve ser utilizada a versão 1.04.00.PkXxGAtPdkWYgZ21TLotsVYYE7mPLGnmpmLMXI65gnQ=NaDYeZv3gFDBH41BY5j8hcYXHhpdx+hjFWCIYvLaBxAVWNUUaAZixzV3Bld4Lul3m0yKL6Hq16xmKYiA55tCPbZWWy+YymnCtj3OC7rZPv2lQZZyTK6DiLugIIiUyk7TsTd1rZmT6D55OxwJfpmb1M+rQLK6siYAZmI2pguUX0NvKITIaaxUD6HGZOgO [...]"
```

Não consigo postar meu XML aqui por limitação de caracteres.

Comment: Vagner, o retorno ficou truncado, poste o XML do retorno na mensagem, seguindo o padrão de formatação da edição que eu fiz.

Comment: Reeditei a pergunta para postar formatado.

Comment: Vagner, mas, quando você diz que "fez a edição", você não fez manualmente não, certo? Porque se você alterar qualquer coisa no arquivo depois de assinado, dará errado. Então, o seu programa tem que pegar apenas o XML do evento (aquele `<Reinf>` com `xmlns=".../evtInfoContribuinte/...`), assinar e embutir a assinatura dentro dele. Aí esse XML do evento, assinado, você embute dentro do lote (o `<Reinf>` com `xmlns=".../envioLoteEventos/...`), e não pode ter nenhuma alteração no XML do evento **depois** de assinado.

Comment: Desculpe a demora em responder. Para teste, eu concatenei manualmente o XML do Lote + o XML do Evento assinado, sem alterar o XML do evento assinado. Mas tudo bem, gostaria de saber o que e como vocês fizeram para unir os 2 XML. Inicialmente eu pensei no XmlTextWriter para ir criando elemento a elemento do XML Lote. No meio do mesmo, pensei em importar o XML do Evento assinado e passar para o XmlTextWriter. De que forma vocês fizeram isso?

Comment: O que eu faço é mais ou menos o que está aqui nessa resposta: [REINF - Assinatura Inválida](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/277475/86952), depois serializo o objeto do lote para um objeto `XElement` e então chamo o método `xElementLote.Save(nomeArquivo)`.

Comment: Vagner, você conseguiu gerar evento assinado e embuti-lo no lote, via código? Se for o caso, abra mais outra pergunta sobre esse assunto. Minha resposta respondeu a sua pergunta original?

Comment: Pedro, infelizmente não tive tempo de aplicar sua sugestão devido outras urgências por aqui. Creio que na segunda feira consigo testar e respondo no post. Obrigado

Comment: Pedro, eu não tenho muita experiência na geração de XML desta forma, por isso talvez minha perguntas sejam bem "básicas". Minha dúvida neste ponto é a seguinte: Será que consigo gerar e validar com sucesso o XML sem serializar? Porque comecei a gera-lo desta forma: A partir do layout do evento, fui utilizando o XmlTexWriter para gerar elemento a elemento do XML com seus respectivos valores até finalizar o arquivo para posterior envio (Consumo do webservice).

Comment: Você precisa serializar, mas não necessariamente gravar em disco. Serializar, nesse caso, é transformar o seu objeto em um XML, mesmo que esse XML esteja somente na memória. Aqui eu mando para o serviço sem nem salvar em disco, mando o XML em memória mesmo, porque na hora de enviar o XML para o serviço você tem que carrega-lo em memória de qualquer forma, em um objeto `XElement`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O XML por padrão é sensível a maiúsculas e minúsculas (*case-sensitive*), e você chamou o elemento raiz do lote como `<REINF>`, mas o esquema XSD diz que o nome deveria ser `<Reinf>`. Altere isso e veja se resolve.

---

Referências:

- [Is XML case-sensitive? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7414747/8133067)
- [Case sensitivity in XML Schema Definitions - Msdn forums](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/03aa269d-4059-435c-8704-9ff9b2e68487/)
- [The XML FAQ: Which parts of an XML document are case-sensitive?](http://xml.silmaril.ie/case.html)

---

**EDIÇÃO**

Eu não havia notado no primeiro momento, mas o problema está na assinatura. Aqui há uma outra resposta que fala sobre isso: [Erro de assinatura do XML para o EFD-Reinf](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/283284/86952).

Mas, basicamente, o seu evento R-1000 deveria estar assim, com a assinatura embutida **dentro** dele:

```xml
      <Reinf xmlns="http://www.reinf.esocial.gov.br/schemas/evtInfoContribuinte/v1_04_00">
        <evtInfoContri id="20181121110000000000000001">
            [...]
        </evtInfoContri>
        <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
            [...]
        </Signature>            
      </Reinf>
```

Você está colocando a assinatura depois do `soap:Body`, o que está **errado**:

```xml
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:sped="http://sped.fazenda.gov.br/">
  <soap:Header />
  <soap:Body>
    <Reinf xmlns="http://www.reinf.esocial.gov.br/schemas/envioLoteEventos/v1_04_00">
      <loteEventos>
        <evento id="ID1">
          <Reinf xmlns="http://www.reinf.esocial.gov.br/schemas/evtInfoContribuinte/v1_04_00">
            <evtInfoContri id="20181121110000000000000001">
              [...]
            </evtInfoContri>
          </Reinf>
        </evento>
      </loteEventos>
    </REINF>
  </soap:Body>
  <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
    [...]
  </Signature>
</soap:Envelope>
```

A forma **correta** do seu `soap:Envelope` deveria ser essa:

```xml
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:sped="http://sped.fazenda.gov.br/">
  <soap:Header />
  <soap:Body>
    <Reinf xmlns="http://www.reinf.esocial.gov.br/schemas/envioLoteEventos/v1_04_00">
      <loteEventos>
        <evento id="ID1">
          <Reinf xmlns="http://www.reinf.esocial.gov.br/schemas/evtInfoContribuinte/v1_04_00">
            <evtInfoContri id="20181121110000000000000001">
              [...]
            </evtInfoContri>
            <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
              [...]
            </Signature>
          </Reinf>
        </evento>
      </loteEventos>
    </REINF>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: Sim.. alterei mas continua retornando a mesma mensagem de versão inválida.