# C# - EFD Reinf v1_04_00 - Como instanciar e preencher todas propriedades dos Eventos?

Tags: c#, web-service

Após minha dúvida respondida aqui:

[EFD-Reinf - Versão do lote inválida. Deve ser utilizada a versão 1.04.00](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/344947/efd-reinf-vers%C3%A3o-do-lote-inv%C3%A1lida-deve-ser-utilizada-a-vers%C3%A3o-1-04-00/344968#344968)

E na pergunta:
[REINF - Assinatura Inválida](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/248928/reinf-assinatura-inv%C3%A1lida/277475#277475)

Foi esclarecido que preciso serializar o xml. 
Através do XSD, gerei as classes no c#, também utilizando a dica do 
@Pedro Gaspar :
[XSD.EXE Gerar classes no C# - EFD Reinf v1_04_00](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/347864/xsd-exe-gerar-classes-no-c-efd-reinf-v1-04-00)

Até aqui OK, chego no momento de de instanciar a(s) classe(s) gerada(s):
(Aqui no caso o registro R-1000):

```
 var cadastro = new Reinf();

 cadastro.evtInfoContri.id = "1000";
 cadastro.evtInfoContri.ideEvento.tpAmb = 2;
 cadastro.evtInfoContri.ideEvento.procEmi = 1;
 cadastro.evtInfoContri.ideEvento.verProc = "1";
```

Minha primeira idéia, era instanciar o Elemento Raiz do Evento, no caso o **Reinf** e ir preenchendo as propriedades seguintes dos elementos "filhos", um a um.

Olhando a classe gerada pelo XSD.EXE, vi que ele gerou uma classe para cada elemento "grupo" do evento:

```
public partial class Reinf {

    /// <remarks/>
    public ReinfEvtInfoContri evtInfoContri;
}
```

...

```
public partial class ReinfEvtInfoContri {

    /// <remarks/>
    public ReinfEvtInfoContriIdeEvento ideEvento;

    /// <remarks/>
    public ReinfEvtInfoContriIdeContri ideContri;

    /// <remarks/>
    public ReinfEvtInfoContriInfoContri infoContri;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute(DataType="ID")]
    public string id;
}
```

...

```
public partial class ReinfEvtInfoContriIdeEvento {

    /// <remarks/>
    public uint tpAmb;

    /// <remarks/>
    public uint procEmi;

    /// <remarks/>
    public string verProc;
}
```

...

Minha dúvida é:

1: Gerei a classe corretamente pelo XSD.EXE?

2: Se sim, preciso instanciar cada classe correspondente ao grupo para preencher as propriedades? Porque ao tentar preencher as propriedades do evento, ele me retorna erro (por não ter instanciado):

[image: Erro ao preencher propriedades]

3: Como serializo o evento completo ? uma vez que o evento completo é composto de várias classes. Tentei assim e ele só gera o primeiro bloco:

```
    XmlSerializer ArquivoSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Reinf));
    using (FileStream ArquivoStream = new FileStream(@"C:\REINF\ZZZ.XML", FileMode.CreateNew))
    {
        using (XmlWriter ArquivoWriter = XmlWriter.Create(ArquivoStream))
        {
            //ArquivoSerializer.Serialize(ArquivoWriter,  pSerializableObject);

            ArquivoSerializer.Serialize(ArquivoWriter, cadastro);

        }
        //return new FileInfo(ArquivoStream.Name);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Respondendo as perguntas:

## 1: Gerei a classe corretamente pelo XSD.EXE?

Sim, é isso mesmo. Cada grupo de informações precisa ser uma nova classe. E no caso em que o grupo possa ocorrer mais de uma vez, você terá um array de objetos daquela classe.

## 2: Se sim, preciso instanciar cada classe correspondente ao grupo para preencher as propriedades?

Sim, precisa. Toda propriedade que for do tipo "classe personalizada", ou seja, fizer referência a um novo grupo de informações dentro da estrutura do evento, virá com valor `null` e você precisará criar explicitamente um objeto para "jogar nessa propriedade".

**Dica:** Coloque cada classe de evento gerada dentro de um namespace específico, porque todas elas têm o elemento raiz com o mesmo nome, `Reinf`, e quando você adicionar a classe do segundo evento já dará conflito, se não estiverem em namespaces separados. Você pode colocar essa primeira classe no namespace `R1000`, por exemplo:

```
namespace R1000 {
    using System.Xml.Serialization;
    
    public partial class Reinf {
        public ReinfEvtInfoContri evtInfoContri;
    }

    // [...]
}
```

E a criação do objeto do evento R-1000 ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
// Elemento raiz EFD-Reinf.
var r1000 = new R1000.Reinf();

// Evento de informações do Contribuinte.
r1000.evtInfoContri = new R1000.ReinfEvtInfoContri();
// Identificação única do evento.
// Regra de validação: REGRA_VALIDA_ID_EVENTO
r1000.evtInfoContri.id = "ID2333901700001892014020213424700001";

// Informações de Identificação do Evento
r1000.evtInfoContri.ideEvento = new R1000.ReinfEvtInfoContriIdeEvento();
r1000.evtInfoContri.ideEvento.tpAmb = 2;
r1000.evtInfoContri.ideEvento.procEmi = 1;
r1000.evtInfoContri.ideEvento.verProc = "1";

// Informações de identificação do contribuinte
r1000.evtInfoContri.ideContri = new R1000.ReinfEvtInfoContriIdeContri();
r1000.evtInfoContri.ideContri.tpInsc = 1;
r1000.evtInfoContri.ideContri.nrInsc = "";

// Identificação da operação (inclusão, alteração ou exclusão) e das
// respectivas informações do Contribuinte.
r1000.evtInfoContri.infoContri = new R1000.ReinfEvtInfoContriInfoContri();
// Inclusão de novas informações
var inclusao = new R1000.ReinfEvtInfoContriInfoContriInclusao();
// Essa propriedade receberá um objeto de inclusão,
// mas poderia ser alteração ou exclusão também.
r1000.evtInfoContri.infoContri.Item = inclusao

// Período de validade das informações incluídas
inclusao.idePeriodo = new R1000.ReinfEvtInfoContriInfoContriInclusaoIdePeriodo();
inclusao.idePeriodo.iniValid = "2019-01";
//inclusao.idePeriodo.fimValid = "";

// Informações do Contribuinte
inclusao.infoCadastro = new R1000.ReinfEvtInfoContriInfoContriInclusaoInfoCadastro();
inclusao.infoCadastro.classTrib = "";
inclusao.infoCadastro.indEscrituracao = 0;
inclusao.infoCadastro.indDesoneracao = 0;
inclusao.infoCadastro.indAcordoIsenMulta = 0;
inclusao.infoCadastro.indSitPJ = 0;
// A ferramenta XSD.exe cria esses campos '{nomeDoCampo}Specified'
// no caso de campos opcionais, e aí você deve informar manualmente
// se o campo está sendo informado ou não.
inclusao.infoCadastro.indSitPJSpecified = true;

// Informações de contato
inclusao.infoCadastro.contato = new R1000.ReinfEvtInfoContriInfoContriInclusaoInfoCadastroContato();
inclusao.infoCadastro.contato.nmCtt = "";
inclusao.infoCadastro.contato.cpfCtt = "";
inclusao.infoCadastro.contato.foneFixo = "";
inclusao.infoCadastro.contato.foneCel = "";
inclusao.infoCadastro.contato.email = "";

// Informações da(s) empresa(s) desenvolvedora(s) da(s) aplicação(ões) que
// gera(m) os arquivos transmitidos para o ambiente nacional da EFD-Reinf.
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Essa propriedade é um array, porque esse grupo pode ocorrer de 0 a 99 vezes.
inclusao.infoCadastro.softHouse = new R1000.ReinfEvtInfoContriInfoContriInclusaoInfoCadastroSoftHouse[]
   { new R1000.ReinfEvtInfoContriInfoContriInclusaoInfoCadastroSoftHouse()
      {
        cnpjSoftHouse = "";
        nmRazao = "";
        nmCont = "";
        telefone = "";
        email = "";
      }
   };

// [...]
```

Lembrando que o campo `r1000.evtInfoContri.id` tem uma regra específica de montagem, que você pode verificar na página 43 do [Manual de Orientação ao Desenvolvedor EFD-Reinf v1.3.03](http://sped.rfb.gov.br/arquivo/download/2739):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

## 3: Como serializo o evento completo? uma vez que o evento completo é composto de várias classes. Tentei assim e ele só gera o primeiro bloco.

Creio que você possa usar esse código mesmo que você postou na pergunta. O XML gerado só tinha o primeiro bloco porque esse é o único objeto presente na estrutura do evento, todos os outros grupos/objetos estão vazios/nulos. A partir do momento que tudo for preenchido corretamente, ao serializar tudo aparecerá no XML gerado.

Lembrando que, normalmente a classe `XmlSerializer` coloca os atributos `xmlns:xsi` e `xmlns:xsd` no elemento raiz, e, segundo a documentação, só deve haver o namespace do próprio Reinf no elemento raiz.

Como a classe `XmlSerializer` normalmente gera o XML:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Reinf xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
       xmlns="http://www.reinf.esocial.gov.br/schemas/evtInfoContribuinte/v1_04_00">
   [...]
</Reinf>
```

Como deveria ser:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Reinf xmlns="http://www.reinf.esocial.gov.br/schemas/evtInfoContribuinte/v1_04_00">
   [...]
</Reinf>
```

Eu uso as seguintes funções para fazer a serialização dos objetos:

```
// Versão que serializa o objeto para o tipo XDocument.
public static XDocument SerializeToXDoc(object obj)
{
   // O elemento raiz não pode conter os atributos 'xmlns:xsi' e 'xmlns:xsd',
   // mas deve conter o atributo 'xmlns="http://www.reinf.esocial.gov.br/[...]'.
   var ns = GetSerializerNamespace(obj);

   var xDoc = new XDocument();
   using (XmlWriter writer = xDoc.CreateWriter())
   {
      var xs = new XmlSerializer(obj.GetType());
      xs.Serialize(writer, obj, ns);
   }
   return xDoc;
}

// Versão que serializa o objeto para o tipo XmlDocument.
public static XmlDocument SerializeToXmlDoc(object obj)
{
   // O elemento raiz não pode conter os atributos 'xmlns:xsi' e 'xmlns:xsd',
   // mas deve conter o atributo 'xmlns="http://www.reinf.esocial.gov.br/[...]'.
   var ns = GetSerializerNamespace(obj);
 
   var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
   var nav = xmlDoc.CreateNavigator();
   using (XmlWriter writer = nav.AppendChild())
   {
      var xs = new XmlSerializer(obj.GetType());
      xs.Serialize(writer, obj, ns);
   }
   return xmlDoc;
}

private static XmlSerializerNamespaces GetSerializerNamespace(object obj)
{
   // Pega o namespace definido para a classe que se deseja serializar, pelo atributo XML.
   // Exemplo: 'xmlns="http://www.reinf.esocial.gov.br/[...]'.
   var xmlAttrib = (XmlTypeAttribute) Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(obj.GetType(),
                                                                   typeof(XmlTypeAttribute));
   string nsClasse = xmlAttrib?.Namespace ?? "";
   // Informa que o elemento raiz do XML que será gerado não deve incluir os atributos
   // 'xmlns:xsi' e 'xmlns:xsd', mas deve incluir o namespace da classe que se deseja serializar.
   var ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
   ns.Add("", nsClasse);
   return ns;
}
```

Comment: OK.  Devo fazer o mesmo procedimento para o(s) Pacote(s) XSD de Comunicação?      
envioLoteEventos-v1_04_00.xsd por exemplo?

Comment: **Deve fazer** é um termo meio forte, hehe... Você pode fazer assim sim, embora possa fazer de outras formas também, mas eu acho essa mais fácil e prática. Eu faço assim (convertendo o esquema de comunicação em objetos também). Depois eu assino os eventos e vou embutindo no objeto de comunicação (envio do lote), como naquela resposta que te passei (https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/277475/86952), e no final serializo o lote com essas mesmas funções, e aí está pronto para o envio!

Comment: Bem, acredito que evolui, pois na string de retorno já aparece a palavra "SUCESSO"... Value: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxSUCESSO1016286041ERRO1MS0030A estrutura do arquivo XML esta em desconformidade com o esquema XSD. The 'URI' attribute is invalid - The value '' is invalid according to its datatype 'AnyUri'. Me utilizei do post: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/248928/reinf-assinatura-inv%C3%A1lida/   para chegar neste ponto. Gostaria de comentar neste mesmo post pois acredito que meu problema seria uma sequência deste...

Comment: @VagnerCosta, veja essa resposta aqui: [EFD-Reinf: Assinatura inválida - Falha ao verificar a assinatura do documento XML (usando C#)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/277476/86952). No eSocial o atributo `URI` do elemento `Reference` deve ser vazio, mas no EFD-Reinf ele deve conter o ID do evento (aquele mesmo da regra que comentei na resposta), na forma: *"#IdDoEvento"*.

Comment: deu certo!! finalmente consegui transmitir com sucesso! Muito obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: Que bom Vagner! De nada. Ontem mesmo eu postei uma outra pergunta em que modifiquei um pouco essa função de assinatura do XML, especificamente para o EFD-Reinf, talvez te ajude: [EDF-Reinf: Erro Assinatura - Um Contexto XmlDocument é necessário para transformações envelopadas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/349264/86952).

Comment: E, só lembrando, agora que você já tem mais de 15 pontos de reputação você já pode [votar a favor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) de uma resposta ou pergunta. Veja também: [Por que é importante votar?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote). Os votos a favor me ajudam, é claro ;-), mas ajudam a comunidade em geral também. Tente criar um hábito de sempre votar no que achar útil. Só cuidado para não dar muitos votos para uma mesma pessoa em um mesmo dia: [Quais os limites para entrar na regra de fraude de votação?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7430/86952).

Comment: Ah sim, e os votos contra também ajudam a comunidade. Se encontrar uma pergunta ou resposta muito ruins, ou incorretos, vote contra. assim sinaliza para outras pessoas que aquela pergunta ou resposta não é boa.