# EFD-Reinf Assinatura XML - "Elemento Reference mal formado."

Tags: c#, assinatura-digital, web-service

Sou novo na comunidade e estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação em C# para o EFD-REINF. Tive um problema com a assinatura e recebi uma grande ajuda do Pedro neste [link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/349201/edf-reinf-erro-assinatura-um-contexto-xmldocument-%C3%A9-necess%C3%A1rio-para-transform/349264?noredirect=1#comment702988_349264).

Ainda não estou conseguindo enviar o XML do evento R-1000 para o servidor de produção remota, pois estou tendo problemas na minha assinatura: **"Elemento Reference mal formado." na linha "signedXml.ComputeSignature()"**. Alguém mais já passou por esse problema?

Basicamente, criei minha classe de EnvioREINF chamando métodos individuais para cada uma das informações a serem enviadas: R-1000 , R-2010, R-2020...(creio que pode existir uma maneira mais simples de fazer isso, porem como não possuo muita experiencia com Web Service eu implementei ele desta maneira) da seguinte forma:

```
 //R-1000
    public bool EnvioEventoevtInfoContribuinte(Empresa objEmpresa, DateTime periodoApuracao)
    {
        try
        {

            EventosREINF auxiliar = new EventosREINF();
            _reinf.evtInfoContri = auxiliar.EnviarEvtInfoContri(objEmpresa, periodoApuracao);
            ReinfEvtInfoContri evtInfoContri = _reinf.evtInfoContri;


            //serializa o evento informações do Contribuinte
            string xmlEventoInclusao = XMLConverte.SerializaObjeto<ReinfEvtInfoContri>(evtInfoContri);

            //Exibe a lista de certificados para o usuário selecionar
            X509Certificate2 oX509Cert = BuscarCertificadoEmpresa();

            //Adiciona a assinatura digital ao evento
            XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
            Assinar(xmlDoc, oX509Cert, xmlEventoInclusao);

            //XmlDocument xmlReinf = Assinar(xmlEventoInclusao, oX509Cert);

            //Inicializa o vetor de eventos do lote a ser enviado
            REINF.Model.v1_04.TArquivoeReinf[] xmlsEvento = new REINF.Model.v1_04.TArquivoeReinf[1];

            //Adicionar Arquivo XML ao array de Eventos do Lote
            REINF.Model.v1_04.TArquivoeReinf arquivoR_1000 = new REINF.Model.v1_04.TArquivoeReinf
            {
                id = objEmpresa.ToString(),
                Any = xmlDoc.DocumentElement
            };
            xmlsEvento[0] = arquivoR_1000;

            //Adiciona o xml do evento de informações do Contribuinte ao xml do evento de envio
            XmlDocument xmlDocEventoEnvio = AdicionarLoteAoEventoEnvio(xmlsEvento, objEmpresa);

            //Envia arquivo xml para o web service e obtém o xml de retorno
            XmlElement xmlRetorno = EnviarXML(xmlDocEventoEnvio, oX509Cert);
        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }
        return true;
    }

    //R-2010
    public bool EnvioEventoevtServTom(List<NotaFiscal> objNotasFiscais, Empresa objEmpresa, DateTime periodoApuracao)
    {
        try
        {
            ReinfEvtServTom reinfEvtServTom = new ReinfEvtServTom();

            EventosREINF auxiliar = new EventosREINF();

            _reinf.evtServTom = auxiliar.EnviarevtServTom(objNotasFiscais, objEmpresa, periodoApuracao);

            //Exibe a lista de certificados para o usuário selecionar
            X509Certificate2 oX509Cert = BuscarCertificadoEmpresa();

            //Inicializa o vetor de eventos do lote a ser enviado
            REINF.Model.v1_04.TArquivoeReinf[] xmlsEvento = ComunicacaoREINF(objNotasFiscais, oX509Cert).ToArray();

            //Adicionar Arquivo XML ao array de Eventos do Lote
            REINF.Model.v1_04.TArquivoeReinf arquivoR_2010 = new REINF.Model.v1_04.TArquivoeReinf
            {
                id = objEmpresa.ToString(),
            };
            xmlsEvento[0] = arquivoR_2010;

            //Adiciona o xml do evento de informações do Contribuinte ao xml do evento de envio
            XmlDocument xmlR2010 = AdicionarLoteAoEventoEnvio(xmlsEvento, objEmpresa);

            //Envia arquivo xml para o web service e obtém o xml de retorno
            XmlElement xmlRetorno = EnviarXML(xmlR2010, oX509Cert);

            //Converte o xml de retorno para a classe retorno de envio
            ReinfRetornoLoteEventos reinfRetornoLoteEventos = XMLConverte.DeserializaObjeto<ReinfRetornoLoteEventos>(xmlRetorno.OuterXml);


        }
        catch
        {

            throw;
        }
        return true;
    }

    //R-2020
    public bool EnvioEventoevtServPrest(List<NotaFiscal> objNotasFiscais, Empresa objEmpresa, DateTime periodoApuracao)
    {
        try
        {

            ReinfEvtServPrest reinfEvtServPrest = new ReinfEvtServPrest();

            EventosREINF auxiliar = new EventosREINF();

            _reinf.evtServPrest = auxiliar.EnviarevtServPrest(objNotasFiscais, objEmpresa, periodoApuracao);

            //Exibe a lista de certificados para o usuário selecionar
            X509Certificate2 oX509Cert = BuscarCertificadoEmpresa();

            //Inicializa o vetor de eventos do lote a ser enviado
            REINF.Model.v1_04.TArquivoeReinf[] xmlsEvento = ComunicacaoREINF(objNotasFiscais, oX509Cert).ToArray();

            //Adicionar Arquivo XML ao array de Eventos do Lote
            REINF.Model.v1_04.TArquivoeReinf arquivoR_2020 = new REINF.Model.v1_04.TArquivoeReinf
            {
                id = objEmpresa.ToString(),
            };
            xmlsEvento[0] = arquivoR_2020;

            //Adiciona o xml do evento de informações do Contribuinte ao xml do evento de envio
            XmlDocument xmlR2100 = AdicionarLoteAoEventoEnvio(xmlsEvento, objEmpresa);

            //Envia arquivo xml para o web service e obtém o xml de retorno
            XmlElement xmlRetorno = EnviarXML(xmlR2100, oX509Cert);

            //Converte o xml de retorno para a classe retorno de envio
            ReinfRetornoLoteEventos reinfRetornoLoteEventos = XMLConverte.DeserializaObjeto<ReinfRetornoLoteEventos>(xmlRetorno.OuterXml);


        }
        catch
        {

            throw;
        }
        return true;
    }

    private List<TArquivoeReinf> ComunicacaoREINF(List<NotaFiscal> objNotasFiscais, X509Certificate2 oX509Cert)
    {
        List<TArquivoeReinf> loteEnvio = new List<TArquivoeReinf>();

        foreach (NotaFiscal notaFiscal in objNotasFiscais)
        {
            ReinfLoteEventos reinfLoteEventos = new ReinfLoteEventos();

            string xmlEventoInfoContribuinte = XMLConverte.SerializaObjeto<ReinfLoteEventos>(reinfLoteEventos);

            var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
            xmlDoc.LoadXml(xmlEventoInfoContribuinte);


            TArquivoeReinf ObjArqXmlFilho = new TArquivoeReinf
            {
                id = notaFiscal.TipoDocumento.Id.ToString(),
                Any = xmlDoc.DocumentElement
            };

            loteEnvio.Add(ObjArqXmlFilho);
        }
        return loteEnvio;
    }

    public ReinfRetornoLoteEventos RetornoLoteEventos(ReinfRetornoLoteEventos retornoLoteEventosInicial, string xmlRetorno)
    {

        try
        {
            ReinfRetornoLoteEventos reinfRetornoLoteEventos = new ReinfRetornoLoteEventos();
            reinfRetornoLoteEventos = XMLConverte.DeserializaObjeto<ReinfRetornoLoteEventos>(xmlRetorno);


            ReinfRetornoLoteEventosRetornoEventos reinfRetornoLoteEventosRetornoEventos = new ReinfRetornoLoteEventosRetornoEventos
            {
                evento = reinfRetornoLoteEventos.retornoEventos.evento
            };


            REINF.Model.ConsultaEvento_ProducaoRestrita.ConsultaInformacoesConsolidadasRequest consultaInformacoesConsolidadasRequest = new ConsultaEvento_ProducaoRestrita.ConsultaInformacoesConsolidadasRequest
            {
                Body = new ConsultaEvento_ProducaoRestrita.ConsultaInformacoesConsolidadasRequestBody()
            };
            //consultaInformacoesConsolidadasRequest.Body.numeroInscricaoContribuinte = "";
            //consultaInformacoesConsolidadasRequest.Body.numeroProtocoloFechamento = "";
            //consultaInformacoesConsolidadasRequest.Body.tipoInscricaoContribuinte = "";

            REINF.Model.ConsultaEvento_ProducaoRestrita.ConsultasReinfClient consultasReinfClient = new ConsultaEvento_ProducaoRestrita.ConsultasReinfClient();

        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }
        return retornoLoteEventosInicial;
    }

    private XmlDocument AdicionarLoteAoEventoEnvio(TArquivoeReinf[] xmlsEvento, Empresa objEmpresa)
    {
        //Leiaute Mensagem Entrada
        ReinfLoteEventos reinfLoteEventos = new ReinfLoteEventos
        {
            evento = new TArquivoeReinf[1]
        };
        reinfLoteEventos.evento = xmlsEvento;

        //Serializa objeto evento de envio
        string xmlEventoEnvio = XMLConverte.SerializaObjeto<ReinfLoteEventos>(reinfLoteEventos);

        //Converte xml do evento envio para XMLDocumente que será transmitido para o web service
        XmlDocument xmlDocEventoEnvio = XMLConverte.ConverterXMLParaXMLDocument(xmlEventoEnvio);

        return xmlDocEventoEnvio;
    }

    private static string UTF8ByteArrayToString(byte[] characters)
    {
        UTF8Encoding encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
        string constructedString = encoding.GetString(characters);
        return (constructedString);
    }

    public void Assinar(XmlDocument xmlDoc, X509Certificate2 X509Cert, string xmlEventoInclusao)
    {


        // Cria o objeto SignedXml baseado no XmlDocument passado.
        SignedXml signedXml = new SignedXml(xmlDoc);
        signedXml.SigningKey = X509Cert.PrivateKey;
        signedXml.SignedInfo.SignatureMethod = "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256";

        // Checa se foi informado um URI para a referência, se foi acrescenta o "#" no começo.
        xmlEventoInclusao = String.IsNullOrEmpty(xmlEventoInclusao) ? "" : $"#{xmlEventoInclusao}";

        Reference reference = new Reference(xmlEventoInclusao);
        reference.Id = _reinf.evtInfoContri.id;
        reference.AddTransform(new XmlDsigEnvelopedSignatureTransform());
        reference.AddTransform(new XmlDsigC14NTransform());
        reference.DigestMethod = "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256";

        signedXml.AddReference(reference);

        // Carrega o certificado em um objeto KeyInfoX509Data e o adiciona ao objeto KeyInfo.
        KeyInfo KeyInfo = new KeyInfo();
        KeyInfo.AddClause(new KeyInfoX509Data(X509Cert));
        signedXml.KeyInfo = KeyInfo;

        // Calcula a assinatura.
        signedXml.ComputeSignature();

        // Obtém a representação XML da assinatura e a armazena em um objeto XmlElement.
        XmlElement xmlDigitalSignature = signedXml.GetXml();

        // Acrescenta o elemento ao documento XML.
        xmlDoc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(xmlDoc.ImportNode(xmlDigitalSignature, true));

        // Se o primeiro nó do documento for o nó de declaração XML
        // '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>', remove ele.
        if (xmlDoc.FirstChild is XmlDeclaration)
            xmlDoc.RemoveChild(xmlDoc.FirstChild);
    }



    private X509Certificate2 BuscarCertificadoEmpresa()
    {
        X509Certificate2 cert = null;
        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += ValidateRemoteCertificate;

        X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
        store.Open(OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly | OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
        X509Certificate2Collection certcollection = (X509Certificate2Collection)store.Certificates;
        // pick a certificate from the store
        cert = X509Certificate2UI.SelectFromCollection(certcollection,
                "Autenticação do Certificado",
                "Informe um certificao válido", X509SelectionFlag.SingleSelection)[0];

        store.Close();

        return cert;
    }

    private XmlElement EnviarXML(XmlDocument xmlDocEventoEnvio, X509Certificate2 oX509Cert)
    {
        XmlElement xmlResult = null;

        var urlServicoEnvio = @"https://preprodefdreinf.receita.fazenda.gov.br/wsreinf/RecepcaoLoteReinf.svc";
        var address = new EndpointAddress(urlServicoEnvio);
        var binding = new BasicHttpsBinding();

        // Informa que será usado um certificado digital para acessar o serviço.
        binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Certificate;
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls;

        // Cria o objeto cliente (do tipo System.ServiceModel.ClientBase) para acesso ao WebService.
        var recepcaoLoteReinfClient = new RecepcaoLoteReinfClient(binding, address);

        // Passa o certificado digital para o objeto do tipo System.ServiceModel.ClientBase.
        recepcaoLoteReinfClient.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate = oX509Cert;

        // Chama o WebService de fato, passando o XML do lote.
        recepcaoLoteReinfClient.Open();

        // O método espera um objeto do tipo XElement, e retorna outro objeto XElement.
        //xmlResult = recepcaoLoteReinfClient.ReceberLoteEventos(xmlDoc.DocumentElement);
        var retornoEnvioXElement = recepcaoLoteReinfClient.ReceberLoteEventos((XElement.Parse(xmlDocEventoEnvio.OuterXml)));
        recepcaoLoteReinfClient.Close();

        return xmlResult;

    }

    private bool ValidateRemoteCertificate(object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
    {
        // If the certificate is a valid, signed certificate, return true.
        if (sslPolicyErrors == System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors.None)
        {
            return true;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("X509Certificate [{0}] Policy Error: '{1}'",
            certificate.Subject,
            sslPolicyErrors.ToString());

        return false;
    }
```

---

**EDIÇÃO**

Segue o XML que está sendo gerado, ocultando as informações pessoais:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Reinf xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://www.reinf.esocial.gov.br/schemas/envioLoteEventos/v1_04_00">
  <evtInfoContri id="ID1000000000000002018121815063800001" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
    <ideEvento>
      <tpAmb>2</tpAmb>
      <procEmi>1</procEmi>
      <verProc>1.0.0.0</verProc>
    </ideEvento>
    <ideContri>
      <tpInsc>1</tpInsc>
      <nrInsc>00000000000000</nrInsc>
    </ideContri>
    <infoContri>
      <inclusao>
        <idePeriodo>
          <iniValid>2018-12</iniValid>
        </idePeriodo>
        <infoCadastro>
          <classTrib>1</classTrib>
          <indEscrituracao>0</indEscrituracao>
          <indDesoneracao>0</indDesoneracao>
          <indAcordoIsenMulta>0</indAcordoIsenMulta>
          <contato>
            <nmCtt>Nome Contato</nmCtt>
            <cpfCtt>00000000000</cpfCtt>
            <foneFixo>0000000000</foneFixo>
          </contato>
          <softHouse>
            <cnpjSoftHouse>00000000000000</cnpjSoftHouse>
            <nmRazao>Empresa</nmRazao>
            <nmCont>Contato</nmCont>
          </softHouse>
        </infoCadastro>
      </inclusao>
    </infoContri>
  </evtInfoContri>
</Reinf>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creio que o problema esteja nessa linha da função `Assinar`:

```
    reference.Id = _reinf.evtInfoContri.id;
```

Aparentemente você não colocou o código onde você carrega o valor desse campo `_reinf.evtInfoContri.id`, mas, como eu disse na minha outra [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/349264/86952), a propriedade `reference.Id` deve começar com `"#"`, quando houver valor, e esse ID informado também deve existir no documento sendo assinado.

Então, provavelmente essa linha deveria ficar assim:

```
    reference.Id = "#" + _reinf.evtInfoContri.id;
```

Mas, eu sugiro que você passe esse ID como um parâmetro da função de assinatura, como sugeri na outra resposta, porque desse jeito que você fez, você não poderá usar a mesma função de assinatura para os outros eventos, e todos precisam ser assinados.

Outra sugestão: Seria interessante tentar criar uma função única para os 3 eventos que você está tratando (R-1000, R-2010 e R-2020), porque o procedimento para todos os eventos é praticamente idêntico. O código em geral também está meio confuso, inclusive com nomes de variáveis que não correspondem ao que estão armazenando, seria legal dar uma revisada.

E uma última sugestão: Não use blocos `try`/`catch` somente para executar um `throw`, isso não serve para nada, veja essa resposta: [Preciso usar o try/catch em toda a cadeia de um processo? - Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/128775/86952).

Comment: Oi Pedro, muito obrigado pela sua ajuda. O campo "_reinf.evtInfoContri.id" é na verdade uma função que eu criei para pegar a resposta do campo "evtInfoContri.id" onde segui os conselhos da sua outra resposta. Adicionei o "#" e ainda sim continuo com esse problema. 
Não sei se tem algo a ver, mais verificando os posts sobre Reinf, meu XML esta contendo os elementos xmlns:xsi e xmlns:xsd, que normalmente são adicionados automaticamente pelo serializador e eu não sei como remover isso do meu XML.

Comment: Sobre o `reference.Id`: Mas esse ID que você está informando existe no XML? Poste o seu XML na pergunta, e o valor que está sendo informado no campo `reference.Id`, quando o erro ocorre. Sobre os atributos `xmlns:xsi`e `xmlns:xsd`, veja o item 3 dessa resposta: [C# - EFD Reinf v1_04_00 - Como instanciar e preencher todas propriedades dos Eventos?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/348662/86952).

Comment: Vi o XML que você está tentando enviar. O valor que você está informando no campo `reference.Id` é `"#ID100000000000002018121809024900001"`? Deveria ser esse (embora ele esteja errado, veja o item 2 [dessa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/348662/86952) para ver como esse ID deve ser composto)(ou você zerou o início do ID intencionalmente para não mostrar o CNPJ da empresa?). Também vi que você está colocando o atributo `xmlns` nos elementos `<ideEvento>`, `<ideContri>` e `<infoContri>`, mas esse atributo só deveria aparecer no elemento raiz `<Reinf>`.

Comment: Creio que o valor no reference.Id esta correto, pois segui a regra do manual de orientação. Sobre o XML, consegui alguns avanços ontem e irei postar o novo XML agora. Porem ainda estou tendo problemas relativos ao meu reference.URI

Comment: Mas qual é o valor exato que você está informando no `reference.Id`? Ele precisa ser exatamente o valor que está no atributo `id` do elemento `<evtInfoContri>`, adicionado do caractere `"#"` no início.

Comment: Na verdade eu segui sua orientação conforme me orientou naquele outro post; Eu estou pegando o resultado do campo reinf.evtInfoContri.id(ID+1+CNPJ+AAAAMMDDHHMMSS+00001) e adicionando o # no inicio. Verifiquei agora na documentação e ela diz que os ultimos campos seriam o nº sequencial da chave, porem eu estou incrementando com 00001. Esta correto?

Comment: Sim, na verdade essa última parte, o número sequencial, é só para garantir que o ID será único. Suponha que no dia 19/12/2018, às 10:50:31, você enviou 3 eventos. Cada um deve ter um ID único, então o primeiro teria final 00001, o segundo 00002 e o terceiro 00003. E mesmo informando no `reference.Id` exatamente o mesmo ID que está no XML, precedido por `#`, você está recebendo o mesmo erro, de _"Elemento Reference mal formado"_?

Comment: Sim, estou querendo enviar apenas o evento R-1000 para teste, porem na assinatura, na parte que calcula a assinatura eu recebo esse erro do Visual Studio. É necessario informar o reference.URI? Caso afirmativo, qual o valor desse campo?

Comment: No caso do eSocial o `reference.Id` não deve ser informado, e aí a assinatura é efetuada em todo o documento XML,mas no EFD-Reinf parece ser necessário informar o `reference.Id`, e nesse caso deve ser informado `"#" + {Atributo ID do elemento 'evtInfoContri'}`. Mas o seu elemento `<evtInfoContri>` também não deveria ter um atributo `xmlns`, muito menos referenciando o *schema* do *XML Signature*: `"http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"`.

Comment: Entendi, percebi tambem que o meu XML não esta chamando o loteEventos, de Reinf ele ja vai direto para o <evtInfoContri>. Creio que isso tambem esteja atrapalhando minha rotina.

Comment: Não, isso está certo. Esse XML é o do evento, o elemento `loteEventos` é do XML do lote. Depois você precisa pegar esse XML do evento e embutir no XML de lote.

Comment: @User1012, minha resposta respondeu sua pergunta? Se tiver respondido, por favor, marque-a como aceita, clicando no sinal de visto (✓). Mas faça isso apenas quando alguma resposta tiver respondido sua dúvida original. Quando atingir 15 pontos de reputação também poderá [votar a favor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) de uma resposta ou pergunta. Veja: [Alguém me respondeu](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) e [Por que votar?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote). Faça também o [tour], para uma explicação inicial de como o site funciona.

Comment: Oi Pedro, respondeu sim meu caro. Cliquei no visto mais ainda preciso atingir 15 pts de reputacao :(