# Retorno Lote Eventos Reinf - A estrutura do arquivo XML está em desconformidade com o esquema XSD

Tags: c#, xml, web-service

Estou gerando o registro R-1000 para teste de envio no ambiente de produção Restrita do EFD-Reinf e já obtive auxílio da comunidade nas seguintes perguntas:

- [EFD-Reinf Assinatura XML - “Elemento Reference mal formado.”](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/351381/efd-reinf-assinatura-xml-elemento-reference-mal-formado);
- [EFD-Reinf: Erro Assinatura - Um Contexto XmlDocument é necessário para transformações envelopadas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/349201/edf-reinf-erro-assinatura-um-contexto-xmldocument-%C3%A9-necess%C3%A1rio-para-transform).

Eu consigo autenticar e fazer o consumo do serviço com sucesso, porém recebo o seguinte XML de retorno:

```xml
<Reinf xmlns="http://www.reinf.esocial.gov.br/schemas/retornoLoteEventos/v1_04_00">
  <retornoLoteEventos id="ID68469C7A3421BB748AEC90BD323FDFA8">
    <ideTransmissor>
      <IdTransmissor>00000000000000</IdTransmissor>
    </ideTransmissor>
    <status>
      <cdStatus>0</cdStatus>
      <descRetorno>SUCESSO</descRetorno>
    </status>
    <retornoEventos>
      <evento id="ID1968278860001102019010910394300001">
        <Reinf xmlns="http://www.reinf.esocial.gov.br/schemas/evtTotal/v1_04_00">
          <evtTotal id="ID884299533">
            <ideEvento>
              <perApur />
            </ideEvento>
            <ideContri>
              <tpInsc>1</tpInsc>
              <nrInsc>0000000000000</nrInsc>
            </ideContri>
            <ideRecRetorno>
              <ideStatus>
                <cdRetorno>1</cdRetorno>
                <descRetorno>ERRO</descRetorno>
                <regOcorrs>
                  <tpOcorr>1</tpOcorr>
                  <localErroAviso />
                  <codResp>MS0030</codResp>
                  <dscResp>A estrutura do arquivo XML esta em desconformidade com o esquema XSD. The 'http://www.reinf.esocial.gov.br/schemas/evtInfoContribuinte/v1_04_00:classTrib' element is invalid - The value '1' is invalid according to its datatype 'String' - The actual length is not equal to the specified length.</dscResp>
                </regOcorrs>
              </ideStatus>
            </ideRecRetorno>
            <infoRecEv>
              <dhProcess>2019-01-09T11:40:20.8435498-02:00</dhProcess>
              <tpEv>1000</tpEv>
              <idEv>ID1968278860001102019010910394300001</idEv>
              <hash>BkxpXCyuN0HOZVaqxC4QA81P5LtK0XUd8ZsXs1B5c+w=</hash>
            </infoRecEv>
            <infoTotal />
          </evtTotal>
          <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
            <SignedInfo>
              <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315" />
              <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256" />
              <Reference URI="#ID884299533">
                <Transforms>
                  <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" />
                  <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315" />
                </Transforms>
                <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256" />
                <DigestValue>qQay/FoAyhWXgd1Xesk/2IM3kPo+nIZzbYiB9oW/OB0=</DigestValue>
              </Reference>
            </SignedInfo>
            <SignatureValue>[...]</SignatureValue>
            <KeyInfo>
              <X509Data>
                <X509Certificate>[...]</X509Certificate>
              </X509Data>
            </KeyInfo>
          </Signature>
        </Reinf>
      </evento>
    </retornoEventos>
  </retornoLoteEventos>
</Reinf>
```

XML de Envio:

```xml
<Reinf xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://www.reinf.esocial.gov.br/schemas/envioLoteEventos/v1_04_00">
  <loteEventos>
    <evento id="ID1968278860001102019011809000800001">
      <Reinf xmlns="http://www.reinf.esocial.gov.br/schemas/evtInfoContribuinte/v1_04_00">
        <evtInfoContri id="ID1968278860001102019011809000800001">
          <ideEvento>
            <tpAmb>2</tpAmb>
            <procEmi>1</procEmi>
            <verProc>1.00</verProc>
          </ideEvento>
          <ideContri>
            <tpInsc>1</tpInsc>
            <nrInsc>00000000000000</nrInsc>
          </ideContri>
          <infoContri>
            <inclusao>
              <idePeriodo>
                <iniValid>2019-01</iniValid>
              </idePeriodo>
              <infoCadastro>
                <classTrib>1</classTrib>
                <indEscrituracao>0</indEscrituracao>
                <indDesoneracao>0</indDesoneracao>
                <indAcordoIsenMulta>0</indAcordoIsenMulta>
                <contato>
                  <nmCtt>Nome Contato</nmCtt>
                  <cpfCtt>00000000000</cpfCtt>
                  <foneFixo>0000000000</foneFixo>
                </contato>
                <softHouse>
                  <cnpjSoftHouse>00000000000000</cnpjSoftHouse>
                  <nmRazao>RAZÃO SOCIAL</nmRazao>
                  <nmCont>Nome Responsável</nmCont>
                </softHouse>
              </infoCadastro>
            </inclusao>
          </infoContri>
        </evtInfoContri>
        <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
          <SignedInfo>
            <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315" />
            <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256" />
            <Reference URI="#ID1968278860001102019011809000800001">
              <Transforms>
                <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" />
                <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315" />
              </Transforms>
              <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256" />
              <DigestValue>8dVIB5s6fgiCxms/WmUZd/VZIw4tBNSeo4r+AqP7pPM=</DigestValue>
            </Reference>
          </SignedInfo>
          <SignatureValue>[...]</SignatureValue>
          <KeyInfo>
            <X509Data>
              <X509Certificate>[...]</X509Certificate>
            </X509Data>
          </KeyInfo>
        </Signature>
      </Reinf>
    </evento>
  </loteEventos>
</Reinf>
```

Estou utilizando o seguinte código em C# para enviar a requisição:

```cs
private XElement EnviarXML(XmlDocument xmlDocEventoEnvio, X509Certificate2 oX509Cert)
{
    XElement xmlResult = null;

    var urlServicoEnvio = @"https://preprodefdreinf.receita.fazenda.gov.br/wsreinf/RecepcaoLoteReinf.svc";
    var address = new EndpointAddress(urlServicoEnvio);
    var binding = new BasicHttpsBinding();

    // Informa que será usado um certificado digital para acessar o serviço.
    binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Certificate;
    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls;

    RecepcaoLoteReinfClient recepcaoLoteReinfClient = new RecepcaoLoteReinfClient(binding, address);
    recepcaoLoteReinfClient.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate = oX509Cert;
    recepcaoLoteReinfClient.Open();
    xmlResult = recepcaoLoteReinfClient.ReceberLoteEventos((XElement.Parse(xmlDocEventoEnvio.OuterXml)));

    var retornoEnvio = XMLConverte.DeserializeFromXNode<RetornoLoteEventos.Reinf>(xmlResult);
    var eventos = retornoEnvio?.retornoLoteEventos.retornoEventos?.evento;

    foreach (var retornoEvtXml in eventos)
    {
        var retornoEvt = XMLConverte.DeserializeFromXmlNode<RetornoTotalizadorEvento.Reinf>(retornoEvtXml.Any);
        if (retornoEvt.evtTotal.ideRecRetorno.ideStatus.cdRetorno != 0)
            continue;
        var nrRecibo = retornoEvt.evtTotal.infoTotal?.nrRecArqBase;
        var hash = retornoEvt.evtTotal.infoRecEv.hash;
    }

    recepcaoLoteReinfClient.Close();

    return xmlResult;
}
```

Alguem já passou por isso? Não encontrei aqui na comunidade perguntas semelhantes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A descrição do erro já dá a pista:

> A estrutura do arquivo XML esta em desconformidade com o esquema XSD. The 'http://www.reinf.esocial.gov.br/schemas/evtInfoContribuinte/v1_04_00:classTrib' element is invalid - The value '1' is invalid according to its datatype 'String' - The actual length is not equal to the specified length.

Ela diz que o valor `1` que você informou no campo `classTrib` é inválido, e que o comprimento do valor é diferente do comprimento especificado pelo esquema XSD.

Conferindo o leiaute do evento R-1000 na documentação ([v1.4](http://sped.rfb.gov.br/arquivo/show/2778)), nota-se que o campo `classTrib` é do tipo caractere com tamanho 002, e lá diz que deve ser um código existente na [Tabela 8](http://sped.rfb.gov.br/arquivo/show/2779).

Conferindo a mencionada Tabela 8, nota-se que o código na verdade é `01`, então o correto seria:

```xml
<classTrib>01</classTrib>
```

Comment: Pedro, mais uma vez agradeço por me ajudar, realmente era isso mesmo. Agora estou enfrentando o erro MS1010 - ID inválido, porem ainda irei debugar aqui para tentar resolver, caso não consiga retornarei para a comunidade.

Comment: Talvez seja a parte do CNPJ. Na maior parte dos empregadores o número de inscrição que identifica o empregador é definido apenas pelo CNPJ raiz, que são os 8 primeiros dígitos do número. Quando isso acontece, no ID deve ser informado assim também, seguido de zeros, e parece que você não está fazendo assim.