# eSocialBX: Erro 402 - "Solicitação inválida"

Tags: c#, web-service, api

Estou tentando consumir o web service de Consulta aos Identificadores dos Eventos, porém recebo esse retorno:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<eSocial xmlns="http://www.esocial.gov.br/schema/consulta/identificadores-eventos/retorno/v1_0_0">
  <retornoConsultaIdentificadoresEvts>
    <status>
      <cdResposta>402</cdResposta>
      <descResposta>Solicitação inválida. Redefina sua consulta</descResposta>
    </status>
  </retornoConsultaIdentificadoresEvts>
</eSocial>
```

Estou enviando o seguinte XML:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<eSocial xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://www.esocial.gov.br/schema/consulta/identificadores-eventos/empregador/v1_0_0">
  <consultaIdentificadoresEvts>
    <ideEmpregador>
      <tpInsc>1</tpInsc>
      <nrInsc>00000000000000</nrInsc>
    </ideEmpregador>
    <consultaEvtsEmpregador>
      <tpEvt>S-1000</tpEvt>
      <perApur>2018</perApur>
    </consultaEvtsEmpregador>
  </consultaIdentificadoresEvts>
  <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
    <SignedInfo>
      <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315" />
      <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256" />
      <Reference URI="">
        <Transforms>
          <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" />
          <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315" />
        </Transforms>
        <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256" />
        <DigestValue>7vfFTl1HHrHL5V/fTfL5Bmq3gUOarDwzGPhBCwrDKQ0=</DigestValue>
      </Reference>
    </SignedInfo>
    <SignatureValue>...</SignatureValue>
    <KeyInfo>
      <X509Data>
        <X509Certificate>...</X509Certificate>
      </X509Data>
    </KeyInfo>
  </Signature>
</eSocial>
```

Esse é o código que gerou o XML acima (ocultei o CNPJ):

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   // Cria o objeto
   ServicoConsultarIdentificadoresEventosClient client = new ServicoConsultarIdentificadoresEventosClient();
   Modelos.ConsultaIdentificadoresEventos.eSocial esocial = new Modelos.ConsultaIdentificadoresEventos.eSocial();
   esocial.consultaIdentificadoresEvts = new eSocialConsultaIdentificadoresEvts();
   esocial.consultaIdentificadoresEvts.ideEmpregador = new TIdeEmpregador();
   esocial.consultaIdentificadoresEvts.ideEmpregador.tpInsc = 1;
   esocial.consultaIdentificadoresEvts.ideEmpregador.nrInsc = "00000000000000";
   esocial.consultaIdentificadoresEvts.consultaEvtsEmpregador = new TConsultaEventosEmpregador();
   esocial.consultaIdentificadoresEvts.consultaEvtsEmpregador.perApur = "2018";
   esocial.consultaIdentificadoresEvts.consultaEvtsEmpregador.tpEvt = "S-1000";

   // Carrega o certificado 
   X509Certificate2 certificado = new X509Certificate2();
   X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
   store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
   certificado = store.Certificates[1];

   // Serializa o objeto
   var xml = Serialize(esocial);

   // Adiciona o certificado
   SignXmlDoc(xml, certificado);

   // Gera o arquivo XML no disco
   XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(XmlDocument));
   TextWriter txtWriter = new StreamWriter(@"C:\\temp\\Serialization.xml");
   xs.Serialize(txtWriter, xml);
   txtWriter.Close();

   // Define o certificado que será usado na chamada do WS
   client.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate = certificado;

   // Converte de document para element
   XDocument linqXml = XDocument.Parse(xml.OuterXml);

   // Chama o serviço enviando o XML      
   var retorno = client.ConsultarIdentificadoresEventosEmpregador(linqXml.Root);

   // Deserializa o objeto
   Modelos.RetornoIndeitificadoresEventos.eSocial deserialized = new Modelos.RetornoIndeitificadoresEventos.eSocial();
   StringReader reader = new StringReader(retorno.ToString());
   XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Modelos.RetornoIndeitificadoresEventos.eSocial));
   deserialized = (Modelos.RetornoIndeitificadoresEventos.eSocial)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(reader);
   client.Close();
}
```

Usei **xsd.exe** e **svcutil** para gerar os códigos.
Alguém já obteve esse erro e sabe como resolver ou obter mais detalhes?

Comment: Me parece que você não está enviando a requisição no formato ou com valores válidos.

Comment: Esse empregador já tinha algo enviado em 2018? Tente remover os atributos `xmlns:xsi` e `xmlns:xsd` da tag `eSocial`, antes de assinar, para ver se muda alguma coisa; veja o item 3 dessa resposta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/348662/86952

Comment: Sim, o empregador enviou este evento no ano passado. @PedroGaspar usei seus códigos para serializar e remover os 2 atributos, porém continua me retornando a mesma mensagem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Além da dica que dei nos comentários, para você remover os atributos `xmlns:xsi` e `xmlns:xsd` da tag `eSocial`, antes de assinar (veja o item 3 dessa resposta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/348662/86952), eu também notei que na tag `nrInsc` (em `ideEmpregador`) você está colocando 14 zeros, mas creio que nesse campo você deva colocar o CNPJ raiz do empregador, com 8 dígitos.

De qualquer forma o problema não é esse. Eu executei a consulta aqui e recebi o mesmo erro que você.

Desde o começo essa documentação do eSocialBX ([Manual do Desenvolvedor v1.7](https://portal.esocial.gov.br/manuais/manualorientacaodesenvolvedoresocialv1-7.pdf/view)) é bem confusa e eu nunca entendi exatamente onde o S-1000 se encaixava exatamente, e onde o método de consulta de Empregador (que é o que você está usando) se encaixava também, porque o manual diz:

> O método `consultarIdentificadoresEventosEmpregador` permite a consulta aos
>   identificadores dos eventos do empregador que não se enquadram nas categorias de eventos de tabela ou eventos periódicos e não periódicos do trabalhador.

Oras, só sobraria o S-1000, se o encarássemos como 'Evento Inicial' e não de tabela, embora ele tenha exatamente a mesma estrutura dos outros eventos de tabela. Mas então, porque esse método teria um campo para informar o Tipo do Evento (tag `tpEvt`)?

E para piorar ainda mais a confusão, no mesmo manual, na seção do método `consultarIdentificadoresEventosTabela` há um exemplo com o evento S-1000, o que sempre me levou a crer que a consulta do S-1000 deveria de fato ser feita usando o método para tabelas.

Bom, mas afinal, para que serve então o método `consultarIdentificadoresEventosEmpregador`?? Após pensar um pouco e fazer alguns testes, finalmente descobri. Contrariando o que diz o manual, esse método funciona para consultar os eventos periódicos que não fazem referência a algum trabalhador, ou seja, aqueles que se referem ao empregador. Pela lógica, e pelos testes que fiz, são eles:

- **S-1250** - Aquisição de Produção Rural
- **S-1260** - Comercialização da Produção Rural Pessoa Física
- **S-1270** - Contratação de Trabalhadores Avulsos Não Portuários
- **S-1280** - Informações Complementares aos Eventos Periódicos
- **S-1295** - Solicitação de Totalização para Pagamento em Contingência
- **S-1298** - Reabertura dos Eventos Periódicos
- **S-1299** - Fechamento dos Eventos Periódicos
- **S-1300** - Contribuição Sindical Patronal

Eu não consegui concluir o teste por conta do limite de 10 consultas diárias, mas, pelo que entendi os eventos totalizadores do empregador **S-5012** e **S-5013** também podem ser consultados por esse método do empregador, mas, curiosamente, o evento **S-5011** não foi aceito pelo método. Até mandei uma mensagem para a equipe do eSocial perguntando o porquê desse comportamento (e reclamando um pouco da confusão imensa das explicações do manual).

**Conclusão:**
Para consultar o evento S-1000, use o método `consultarIdentificadoresEventosTabela`. Um exemplo de XML:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<eSocial xmlns="http://www.esocial.gov.br/schema/consulta/identificadores-eventos/tabela/v1_0_0">
   <consultaIdentificadoresEvts>
      <ideEmpregador>
         <tpInsc>1</tpInsc>
         <nrInsc>########</nrInsc>
      </ideEmpregador>
      <consultaEvtsTabela>
         <tpEvt>S-1000</tpEvt>
      </consultaEvtsTabela>
   </consultaIdentificadoresEvts>
</eSocial>
```

**Complemento:**
Quando estava revendo a resposta notei um detalhe que nunca havia percebido na documentação:

> O método `consultarIdentificadoresEventosEmpregador` permite a consulta aos
>   identificadores dos eventos do empregador que não se enquadram nas categorias de eventos de tabela ou *eventos periódicos* e *não periódicos* **do trabalhador**.

Ou seja, está lá, mas está de forma tão sutil que imagino que ninguém havia se atentado a esse detalhe.